# Disallow call with any

Tags: typescript

Consider following function overloads:

```
function f(key: undefined);
function f(key: string | undefined, value: object | undefined);
```

I want to make eligible calls with single explicit undefined `f(undefined)`, but require two arguments for all other cases. And overloads above work fine, until I pass a variable with type `any` - seems like `any` can be casted to `undefined` (yes, it seems logical as it is any).

**How can I disallow call with single `any` argumnent?**

---

Full [demo code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20f(key%3A%20undefined)%3B%0D%0Afunction%20f(key%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%2C%20value%3A%20object%20%7C%20undefined)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f(key%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%2C%20value%3F%3A%20object%20%7C%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(key%2C%20value)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20No%20errors%20-%20RIGHT%0D%0Af(undefined)%3B%0D%0Af(%22%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0Af(%22%22%2C%20undefined)%3B%0D%0Af(undefined%2C%20undefined)%3B%0D%0Af(undefined%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Errors%20-%20RIGHT%0D%0Af(%22%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20No%20errors%20-%20WRONG%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20x%3A%20any%3B%0D%0Af(x)%3B):

```
function f(key: undefined);
function f(key: string | undefined, value: object | undefined);

function f(key: string | undefined, value?: object | undefined) {
    console.log(key, value);
}

// No errors - RIGHT
f(undefined);
f("", {});
f("", undefined);
f(undefined, undefined);
f(undefined, {});

// Errors - RIGHT
f("");

// No errors - WRONG
declare var x: any;
f(x);
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

TypeScript really doesn't want to disallow `any` from matching a type, since that's the whole point of `any`.  You might want to rethink any code which relies on rejecting `any`, so tread lightly.

---

That being said, you can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to build a detector for `any` which can then be used to disallow an `any` variable.

Here's the detector:

```
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N;
```

The type constraint `0 extends 1` is not satisfied (`0` is not assignable to `1`), so it should be impossible for `0 extends (1 & T)` to be satisfied either, since `(1 & T)` should be even narrower than `1`.  However, when `T` is `any`, it reduces `0 extends (1 & any)` to `0 extends any`, which is satisfied.  That's because `any` is intentionally [unsound](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-compatibility#soundness) and acts as both a supertype and subtype of *almost* every other type.  Therefore, `IfAny<T, Y, N>` checks if `T` is `any`.  If so, it returns `Y`.  If not, it returns `N`.  Let's see it work:

```
type IsAny<T> = IfAny<T, true, false>
const yes: IsAny<any> = true;
const no: IsAny<string> = false;
```

---

Recall that I said `any` matches *almost* every other type.  The only type that *doesn't* match `any` is `never`:

```
declare const any: any;
const never: never = any; // error, any is not assignable to never
```

We need that fact too, in order to reject `any` parameters.  Let's change the first signature of `f()` from

```
function f(key: undefined): void;
```

to

```
function f<K extends IfAny<K, never, undefined>>(key: K): void;
```

We've made the `key` a generic type `K` that is constrained to `IfAny<K, never, undefined>`.  If `K` is not `any`, then that constraint is just `undefined`, so `K` can only be `undefined` as desired.  If `K` *is* `any`, then that constraint becomes `never`, and since `any` does not match `never`, it will fail to meet the constraint.

When we use the above signature, you see the following behavior:

```
f(undefined); // still works
f(""); // still error, "" is not assignable to undefined

declare var x: any;
f(x); // now error, any is not assignable to never
```

which is what you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZgQQHYgDwBUA0UCa2ByAfFALxQAMUEAHsBEgCYDOUAFAIxQBkU6AlFAD8uKAC4o+ANxQAUHNCRYTZGnTEy8FRmzAATgFcI2OAEMANkwiEZAYwD2SJsCggITcTGUpUJlOqh6hpK2Dk5QSHYeXmhOugCWSADm-qYWEMFyDBA2Zia60PaOzr4g4iXBhWFIEABuELri1XW6pFDlUAD0HVS6una62CVQcSwRxUxMcYlIJgBGZtDAduG19ZnZuflQcPpINsBxDtuoANJUtPTMsIjeJ9hN9di7WXAJEAyEhKwA1hClUCc+OIanY4gwMnBWM8IK9qgw+NIulAnHEzGYoAB3frfJgySEAInxCM63RRaJ6fQGUEJw1GdnGk2mcwWAWW0Nh73WOTy0BqeSg1DKKGCkOoxKREQxFP6gxQtPC9LaEymM3mi2WD10MiAA)

Comment: Thank you! Great solution! But you have to note that it works only with `strictNullChecks` enabled. Otherwice `f(undefined)` produces an error too.

Comment: Ah, yes, I never tried with `strictNullChecks` off.

Comment: How can I change this solution to make it work with generic parameters? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55577863/4928642 // cc @TitianCernicova-Dragomir

Comment: @Qwertiy I agree with jcalz's answer over there