# TypeScript: Return type has all keys specified as parameter

Tags: typescript

I would like to type a function in a way, that the return type will be an object, that contains exactly the keys specified in an array as a parameter. Also these keys should all be of a specific enum type. I've already tried a couple of things, but can't get it working. Maybe someone knows if it's possible at all and how?

```
enum Status {
  TIME = 'time',
  LOCATION = 'location'
}

function getStatus(statusToGet: Status[]) {
  // This function will always return an object containing all passed in
  // status as a key and boolean as a value, e.g.
  return statusToGet.reduce((prev, stat) => {
    prev[stat] = true; // or false
    return prev;
  }, {});
}

getStatus([]) // -> {}
getStatus([Status.TIME]) // -> { time: true }
getStatus([Status.TIME, Status.LOCATION]) // -> { time: true, location: false }
```

Is it possible to type the `getStatus` function correctly, so that TS knows which keys are in the return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mapped types to map an array of string literal types to an object :

```
enum Status {
    TIME = 'time',
    LOCATION = 'location'
}

function getStatus<T extends Status>(statusToGet: T[]): { [P in T]: boolean } {
    return null as any;
}

getStatus([]) // -> {}
getStatus([Status.TIME]) // -> { time: true }
getStatus([Status.TIME, Status.LOCATION]) // -> { time: true, location: false }
```

**Note** The above code returns `{ [s:string] :any}` for an empty array if strict null checks are not enabled. This happens because `T` will be inferred to `any`. To get around this we can use a conditional type to test if `T` is `any` and return `{}` explicitly (10x to @jcalz for the any test from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927523/disallow-call-with-any/49928360#49928360)). This does mean any array of `any` will produce `{}` but since we expect an array of enum values not an array of any this migh not be too much of a problem, might actually be a feature.

```
function getStatus<T extends Status>(statusToGet: T[]): true extends false & T?  {} : { [P in T]: boolean } {
     return null as any;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that seems to work exactly! Thanks. I somehow always tried to put the whole array in the generic type :'D Will mark as correct as soon as the blocking time is over.

Comment: This was my approach as well, but the first example (with the empty array) has a return type of `{[x: string]: boolean}`, which allows any key. Is it possible to have it return the empty object `{}` without the index signature somehow?

Comment: I've tried the above, and when passing in an empty array, it returns an empty object for me?

Comment: @CRice added a version that works with stric null checks off