# Typescript: restrict decorator via TypedPropertyDescriptor on decorator factories

Tags: node.js, typescript

I know that the standard way to restrict what a decorator can apply on is to use a TypedPropertyDescriptor, a la `export function decorator(target, key, TypedPropertyDescriptor<T extends ...>) {...}`

This works fine when used as is. But if a decorator factory is involved, the TS compiler no longer seems to enforce it.

i.e: `export function whatever (param: SomeThing) { return function decorator(target, key, TypedPropertyDescriptor<T extends ...>) {...} }`

You can put this (^) on anything you like, which defeats the purpose. How does one restrict decorators when used via factories?

I tried searching around, but couldn't quite find anything.

Full example:

```
export function AsyncEndpoint(
    method: string,
    path: string,
    model?: ClassType<IRequest>,
    validationRules: any = {},
    responseStatus: number = HttpStatus.OK,
    base: string = "v1"
) {
    // noinspection TsLint
    return function(
        target: Controller, // This is the class prototype
        propertyKey: string, // This is the prop/method name called
        descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...p: any[]) => Promise<any>>
    ): any {...}
```

Comment: Where is your type parameter defined ? Could you provide a full example? It work fine in my experiments ..

Comment: Ex: `function whatever (param: SomeThing) { 
    return function decorator<T extends ()=> string>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>)
    {} 
}

class test {
  @whatever(new SomeThing()) /*err*/
  m(){ }
  @whatever(new SomeThing()) /*ok*/
  mw(): string{ return "" }
}`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - I added the full example, please take a look. The idea is to prevent it from being applied to synchronous methods.

It currently can be applied fine.

Comment: I get an error if I try to apply it on methods that do not return a `Promise`, the single exception is methods returning `any`..  Could you post a full example that reproduces the issue ? Including the target class. Here is my stackblitz showing it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xh9n49

Comment: I'll try tomorrow during work hours and get back to you.

Comment: Yep, the issue was a any return type. Not sure how I missed that, thank you for the assist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was cause by the fact that the function retunred any and the decorator would be compatible with `any` since `any` is compatbile with any constraint.

You can avoid the decorator being compatible with a function returning any using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927523/disallow-call-with-any/49928360#49928360) trick to detect `any`:

```
class SomeThing { }
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N; 
function whatever(param: SomeThing) {
    return function decorator<T extends () => Promise<any>>(target: Object,
        propertyKey: string | symbol,
        descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> & IfAny<ReturnType<T>, "Any not allowed retrun a promise", {}>) {

    }
}
class test {
    @whatever(new SomeThing()) /*err*/
    m() : any{
    }
    @whatever(new SomeThing()) /*ok*/ mw() {
        return Promise.resolve("")
    }
}
```

Comment: @PaulS. Glad to help, don't forget to give jcalz an upvote in the link, he is the source of the `IfAny` type :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that our signature for these methods was effectively `any`, which `Promise<any>` fullfills.

Many thanks to @TitianCernicova-Dragomir for helping to figure this out.