# Typescript check for the 'any' type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to check for the exact `any` type using typescript conditionals?

```
type IsAny<T> = T extends any ? true : never

type A = IsAny<any> // true
type B = IsAny<number> // never
type C = IsAny<unknown> // never
type D = IsAny<never> // never
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disallow call with any](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928360/2887218)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yeah, you can test for `any`:

```
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N; 
type IsAny<T> = IfAny<T, true, never>;
type A = IsAny<any> // true
type B = IsAny<number> // never
type C = IsAny<unknown> // never
type D = IsAny<never> // never
```

The explanation for this is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927523/disallow-call-with-any/49928360#49928360).  In short, `any` is intentionally unsound, and violates the normal rules of types.  You can detect this violation because it lets you do something crazy like assign `0` to `1`.

Comment: The simpler one `type IfAny<T, Y, N> = T extends never ? Y : N; ` also seems to have same effect. It looks like `T extends never` is distributed over `T` even when `T` is `never`, not sure if it's intended or not.

Comment: @artem That is intended; `never` is considered the "empty union" so it [always maps to `never` in a distributive conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182#issuecomment-379094672).  It is interesting that `any` doesn't get distributed, which is why that version of `IfAny` can distinguish `any` from `never`... of course it does so by returning `never` instead of `N`, which is probably not desired.

Comment: This one from `@types/react` emits false (not never) when T is never: `type IsExactlyAny<T> = boolean extends (T extends never ? true : false) ? true : false;`

Answer (score 5):

another way to detect IsAny:

```
type IsAny<T> = (
  unknown extends T
    ? [keyof T] extends [never] ? false : true
    : false
);
```

[image: result of IsAny with some values]

Answer (score 2):

You can (ab)use the fact that [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#any-unknown-object-void-undefined-null-and-never-assignability) is both a *subtype* and a *supertype* of almost<sup>1</sup> everything. So the inner [(Distributive) Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) resolves to a [Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `true | false` (=`boolean`) instead of either of them. I checked if `T extends never` but it works with pretty much any other type too.

```
type IsAny<T> = boolean extends (T extends never ? true : false) ? true : false;

type A = IsAny<any> // true
type B = IsAny<number> // false
type C = IsAny<unknown> // false
type D = IsAny<never> // false
type E = IsAny<void> // false
type F = IsAny<{}> // false
type G = IsAny<object> // false
type H = IsAny<undefined> // false
type I = IsAny<null> // false
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgQQHYgDwBUB8UC8UBGA9oQDYQCGSUEAHsBEgCZxQAU61dDzUSEAbhABOUAPxRgQgK7QAXFABm5EnAgBKMROlzFy1QG4AsACgToSFAS5YiFKkohsAeidaZZ8NABC1+MjRIUgC2+MLOrkoqEB4WAMK+tmhSSADWSIQA7kjhulEx0AAiCf6ofIJCOZGq+VAAosV2-IQAloyVetHG5tAAYg1oAN4Avu15XZ5QAOL9qIT4AFYQAMbAo9XjFgASM8mMEArNfG1QLrnr3bAzgSQkaxBAA)

---

<sup>1</sup> except for `never`