# Discriminate function return type based on inferred parameter type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to express exactly the type of a simple function which checks some condition and returns a value or else returns a default. Since the default is a constant in most cases, it would make sense to return a union of expected and default value types so it would be properly narrowed at the call site.

First, the function and expected use cases.

```js
const f = (
  value: unknown, defaultValue?: string | null | undefined
): string | null | undefined => {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return value;
  }

  return defaultValue;
};

const s1: string = f('', 's');
const s2: string | null = f('', null);
const s3: string | undefined = f('', undefined);
const s4: string | undefined = f('');
const x: string | null | undefined = '';
const s5: string | null | undefined = f('', x);
```

The type of first argument is always the same, it does not actually affect the discrimination, added just for simple code example. Output type always contains string. The discrimination should only affect if the output type contains null and undefined depending on the type of default parameter at the call site.

With the specified function type, compiler obviously complains on cases 1-4.

Now my various attempts to define a discriminating type.

```
interface I {
  (value: unknown, defaultValue: string): string;
  (value: unknown, defaultValue: null): string | null;
  (value: unknown, defaultValue?: undefined): string | undefined;
  // (value: unknown, defaultValue?: string | null | undefined): string | null | undefined;
}

type T1 = ((value: unknown, defaultValue: string) => string) | 
  ((value: unknown, defaultValue: null) => string | null) | 
  ((value: unknown, defaultValue?: undefined) => string | undefined) |
  ((value: unknown, defaultValue: string | null | undefined) => string | null | undefined)

type T2 = <U extends string | null | undefined> (
  value: unknown, defaultValue?: U
) => string | U;
```

Interface I with overloads satisfies all use cases, but f is not assignable to it even if I uncomment the last overload which exactly matches f's type. And overloads are verbose.

f is assignable to T1, but it does not work as overloads.

T2 is concise, satisfying all use cases, but still, f is not assignable to it. Additionally, T2 allows wrong use case like `const incorrect: number = f('', <any>1);`, because `extends` is too forgiving.

Is there a way to create a type which would describe the same overloads as the interface above? And declare the same function so it would be assignable to the interface or type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `T2` might be close enough for practical purposes, but note that `f('')` returns type `string | null | undefined`.  If I wanted to try to get it more exactly, I'd do something like this:

```
const f = <T extends [(string | null)?]>(
    value: unknown, ...[defaultValue]: T
): string | T[0] => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return value;
    }
    return defaultValue;
};
```

This uses [rest parameters and tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to capture the fact that when `defaultValue` is omitted, you want the generic type parameter to be `undefined` and not `string | null`.  It's a quirk of type inference that `g<T extends A>(x?: T): void` will infer `A` for `T` when you call `g()` with no argument, but `g<T extends [A?]>(...[x]: T): void` will infer `[]`, and so `T[0]` is `undefined`.

You can see that all your use cases work:

```
const s1 = f('', 's'); // string
const s2 = f('', null); // string | null
const s3 = f('', undefined); // string | undefined 
const s4 = f(''); // string | undefined 
const x = ["", null, void 0][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]; // string | null | undefined
const s5 = f('', x); // string | null | undefined
```

So maybe instead of `T2` you want

```
// typeof f
type T3 = <T extends [(string | null | undefined)?]>(
    value: unknown, ...[defaultValue]: T
) => string | T[0];
```

You'll find that *this* works with `I`:

```
const i: I = f; // okay
```

---

About your aside that using `T2` (or `T3`) leads to this:

```
const incorrect = f('', <any>1); // any ‍
```

I'm inclined to say "caveat emptor" to someone who uses values of type `any`, since it often pollutes the type system in insidious ways.  There are ways to [detect `any`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541275/typescript-check-for-the-any-type) if you really wanted to do that, although the function typing becomes more obnoxious than I'd think is worth it:

```
type IfAny<T, Y, N = T> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N;
const g = <T extends [(string | null)?]>(
    value: unknown, ...[defaultValue]: T
): string | IfAny<T[0], null | undefined> => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return value;
    }
    return defaultValue as any;
};

const gs1 = g('', 's'); // string
const gs2 = g('', null); // string | null
const gs3 = g('', undefined); // string | undefined 
const gs4 = g(''); // string | undefined 
const gs5 = g('', x); // string | null | undefined
const betterMaybe = g('', <any>1); // string | null | undefined
```

Yay?  Who knows.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgGYILwIDwBUEFMAecuUAJjAgNoAU8ATgJZQDmCAPglAK4A23AlAH4AugD4qoBJIQA3AIbdOuAFwJOUANZQIAdygAaBADpjFEriSyecAGrzFQlVlB8VdRi3ZYKABiFoRCADeElL0KFRwAJ4ADrgQKHIKuGio6ADkbsxpfEEhUlK0uHCctFAydrgA3HkIAL41hcWlCGYWVrZJ1SC1XaBRsQhYAMxomDgERKTk1JkeHDzcbKqk5oy4JIKi4iD5iYoqapo6+kYmrZbcNhUOg87+CLNLXr69IKCMRLQWYMkAkrk7KRUPbKZZHXQGc7tCquOAMZguB5w9xdfLAmFgrQQlrmC5XJIqLi8RGPdhE7iooEgg4aLEnKGXDqKAQ01prDaw+FzNRsqDrSmSdEEzHHSG46FJFlIrlLclLHmrPkc6XuWULeUrJDsrr1N7gaDwBD0FT-dBISoIAD0loQEHUskioFAkFgiBgAEZRkgqGk0gYMtkLdaVcxnQa3QAmL0+v3zYlBm2kuPcMOuh4jM0xgwKrVKvgJkPczXshCpw0wAAs0d9+atieRzA1vPWpf1afwowoACIuwZyQZpBB6CQEL4KABZWRwAAWhiQ3AgEFoVEnM8MtFkpAgAFsqDkAFQIIZ8IQFpNy9g59llt0AVmrsfwteD5-Vl+LSqdbcNjEgtEKYCIJmvoGBgm6RCI7rPja4EIIAfBuAOy7gCwBF+-R-EgACCUCRNgBgAJoGAAcqMWABOg3h4IQxBkAgVCegAZIMOQCAgeEICohFdC6hosOg2CUZMNEzA2czkpsYg1NSIrYsYhimOKjLXI4zicqq7C-Jh2HYD4Qh9m+yzNiQZEBMEgKSGEtFofE5RJCk6SzNkAL5PkjQlGUIICnUDRFG5OJtIptmyOQ4E6q83GIEwHqjEwWYIAG0GFjeCCRVG6AxSByYJa+vBJZFGbJbFV55meIlNoqLa5ZW0UxllpXvoZrbhclMD3mlsVPiVMpkvpRXrElABGRSfJOkSDdVGVgdhkG1V1yZlbmfUgEAA)

Comment: Fantastic! A lot of clever hacks. I need to meditate on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to make the discriminated types to work with `f`:

```
interface IDiscriminate {
    (value: string, defaultValue?: unknown): string;
    <T>(value: unknown, defaultValue?: T): T;
}

const f: IDiscriminate = <T>(value: unknown, defaultValue?: T) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return value;
    }
    return defaultValue;
};

const s1: string = f('', 's');
const s2: string = f('', null);
const s3: string = f('', undefined);
const s4: string = f('');
const x: string = 'x';
const s5: string = f('', x);
const s6: string = f(1, x);
const s7: null = f(1, null);
const s8: undefined = f(true);
const s9: number = f(1, 1);
//const incorrect: number = f('', <any>1); // Fails to compile
```

#### Testing

```
console.log(`s1 === '': ${s1 === ''}`); // true
console.log(`s2 === '': ${s2 === ''}`); // true
console.log(`s3 === '': ${s3 === ''}`); // true
console.log(`s4 === '': ${s4 === ''}`); // true
console.log(`s5 === '': ${s5 === ''}`); // true
console.log(`s6 === 'x': ${s6 === 'x'}`); // true
console.log(`s7 === null: ${s7 === null}`); // true
console.log(`s8 === undefined: ${s8 === undefined}`); // true
console.log(`s9 === 1: ${s9 === 1}`); // true
```

You can see the results of running the test in [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=63&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBFgGcFWAW1DkmQG8AoZK5ACgDc4AbAVwgC5ksw8QBzAGmQATCPGaMwANSasA-B2YgA1iAD2AdxABKDlx68A3JWoAeACoA+ejPbJFKjSEEixE6SwjzkZnd6MBfcnIEVRAuZBgODGxcAiISAF5kcysGDwVlNU1nUThxKRsvH2QEizJjKmAYWjAATwAHCFVqtNYShKSAcj1QXk6tcuoh5CgIMGYoEGRWiCMhwKHR8cnhXPz3VgCjYNDwrABGXW5ekoiaTs7Bbv6jELCwTgAmI-1TmHPL5BBxRi1b3YeWAAzC8Tkl3hdBIoXKAIEI-jt7pwACygvhvD4Iu7hAAeaN4p06OM6-yRWAArPiMZDkDisQDOAA2Kngmj7QR00l7ADsHG+jEYGPZXx+9LJAA4MjCQHCMdxWGK9gBOPnMfAAI2gQsE+wRAHo9diHqAQlBRggwKqNVrWTSTHAQLULLqDMgDcgAGJwYCMLDIMCqZAhfD1H0QILY1SMCAAOkYql4NAABgd2l1OhwACSkVMddP+JN-N16-1QViIrBR2PxxMpx5p5AXLM5+t5xudAtF93y8OR6NxhPJ4ENpvIbPDtsXTuu7tl3u7KsD2tYZEjjNjnOrycdwszks9iuLmtD8lr5sUtfT4ul8t96uDlOMkfE89PyfEq+z28L-vHlPcht+UYc8ALbIDP33OdD1-B8sHFBtoVEWEhHPeC20QmBkIgm95zCI9YKVBtDg3LBCLbfZsJ7IA)

Comment: I should have been more clear that the type of first argument is always the same (is not used in discrimination, added just for simple code example) and output type always contains string. The discrimination should only affect if the output type contains null and undefined depending on type of default parameter.

Comment: @KonstantinPelepelin See if my edit fixes it, otherwise please edit your original question with more detail and you can use this answer as reference of what you are not looking for