# Trying to make a wrapper for react-form-hook and GraphQL Mutation, but how do I specify the Generic Types so they ar not unrelated anymore?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

> [edit] I've created a very simplified example of what my problem is: https://codesandbox.io/s/example-type-inference-for-generic-types-qyqz1?file=/src/index.ts

So I'm trying to make a wrapper that accepts the `form-handler` and `mutation` (generated with `graphql-let`), to return a function that can be used in a form.

This is the code, but it throws an error on the `variables` in `mutation({ variables: {...})` (see below).

> Type '{ input: UnpackNestedValue; }' is not assignable to type 'TVariables'.
> 'TVariables' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ input: UnpackNestedValue; }'.ts(2322)
> types.d.ts(92, 5): The expected type comes from property 'variables' which is declared here on type 'MutationFunctionOptions<TData, TVariables>'

I understand that `TVariables` and `TData` can be different, but `TVariables` has default of `OperationVariables` which is type `{ [key: string]: any }`, which is pretty generic.

How to solve this?

```js
import {
  FetchResult,
  MutationFunctionOptions,
  OperationVariables,
} from '@apollo/client';
import { UseFormHandleSubmit } from 'react-hook-form';

export const submitHandlerMutationFactory = <
  TForm,
  TData,
  TVariables = OperationVariables
>(
  submitHandler: UseFormHandleSubmit<TForm>,
  mutation: (
    options?: MutationFunctionOptions<TData, TVariables>
  ) => Promise<FetchResult<TData>>
) => {
  return submitHandler((data) => mutation({ variables: { input: data } }));
};
```

*EDIT after Kiuhnm's answer*

It doesn't give the error anymore, but now I'm also missing the goal: getting the function to make sure the Types of the `submitHandler` and the `mutation` are the same.

However, if I use this, we get problems with the `input` variable, similar to previous problem, but it DOES give me information over when calling the the function with two not-matching types.

```js
export const submitHandlerMutationFactory = <TFormInputs, TMutation>(
  submitHandler: UseFormHandleSubmit<TFormInputs>,
  mutation: Apollo.MutationTuple<TMutation, { input: TFormInputs }>[0]
) => {
  return submitHandler((data) => mutation({ variables: { input: data } }));
  // Type 'UnpackNestedValue<TFormInputs>' is not assignable to type 'TFormInputs'.
  //   'TFormInputs' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be
  //   unrelated to 'UnpackNestedValue<TFormInputs>'.ts(2322)
};

const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  watch,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm<LoginFormInputs>();

const [loginMutation, { data, loading, error }] = useLoginMutation();

type LoginFormInputs = {
  username: string;
  SOMETHING: string; // see explicit error below
};

const formSubmitHandler = submitHandlerMutationFactory(
  handleSubmit,
  loginMutation
  // Property 'password' is missing in type 'LoginFormInputs' but required in type 'LoginInput'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`f1` and `f2` can't be composable in this way, because `f2` return type is incompatible with `f1` argument type. Not sure how you want to compose them.

```js
function f1(param: { x: string; y: number }) {
  return { a: param.x, b: param.y };
}

function f2(param: { a: string; b: number }) {
  return param;
}

function wrapperFactory<T1, T2>(
  fn1: (param: T2) => T2,
  fn2: (param: T1) => T2
) {
  return (param: T1) => fn1(fn2(param));
}

// none of these called functions have to pass the generic type
// they still are being validated perfectly

// ERROR
wrapperFactory(f1, f2)({ x: "", y: 0 });

// ERROR
wrapperFactory(f1, f2)({ b: "", y: 0 });

// ERROR
wrapperFactory(
  (param: { g: number; h: string }) => ({ a: param.h, b: param.g }),
  f2
)({ a: "", g: 0 });
```

I'm unable to reproduce any of your examples. Could you please share them in codesanbox? just like you shared your first example.

P.S. It seems that you want to use function composition. If yes, please take a look on [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319258/how-to-type-pipe-function-using-variadic-tuple-types-in-typescript-4/68513136#68513136) and [compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057205/typescript-reduce-an-array-of-function/67760188#67760188) examples.