# In typescript, how to define a type for first element function and extract result of previous element function as parameters of next element function

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, type-inference

How to define first element as type First and extract result of previous element as parameters of next function.

```js
type First = (a: number) => any;
const fns = [
  (a) => a.toString(), // a => number;
  (b) => parseInt(b), // b => string
  (c) => c + 1, // c => number
  (d) => d.toString() // d: number
]
```

I need a, b, c, d, ...etc have to be defined.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319258/how-to-type-pipe-function-using-variadic-tuple-types-in-typescript-4/68513136#68513136) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057205/typescript-reduce-an-array-of-function/67760188#67760188) you will find related questions/answers

Comment: If you intend to compose these functions together, then you can une a library like [Ramda.pipe](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe), which will do the inference of types for you (with `@types/ramda` installed)

Comment: Checkout [the source of Ramda.pipe here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/68c911e5b26e3294c61dbaac500384835f009c18/types/ramda/index.d.ts#L1619) to see how they did it. It quite clunky but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure this was your question, but I believe an array of functions makes those functions unrelated to each other from the type system perspective. You can't ensure they will be called in order, so you can't really describe this situation in terms of types.
Why not simply:

```
const fns = [
  (a: number): string => a.toString(), // a => number;
  (b: string): number => parseInt(b), // b => string
  (c: number): number => c + 1, // c => number
  (d: number): string => d.toString() // d: number
]
```

Or, maybe let's take a step back and explain what problem you are solving - maybe there's a better pattern than an array of functions that need to be called in order? I have a feeling a function composition might be what you're looking for: https://minaluke.medium.com/typescript-compose-function-b7512a7cc012