# Can you write a `Compose` method that infer types correctly if the innermost function is generic

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to develop a middleware layer for my lambda application. The idea is that I can compose all the middleware together and apply then to my final handler.

```js
interface APIGatewayProxyEventV2 {
  body: string;
}

interface Context {
  awsRequestId: string;
}

type APIGatewayProxyResultV2<T = never> = string | T;

type Lambda<TResult = any> = (
  event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2,
  context: Context
) => Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2<TResult>>;

const firstMiddleware =
  <TResult>() =>
  (handler: Lambda<TResult>): Lambda<TResult> =>
  async (event, context) => {
    console.log("firstMiddleware");
    return await handler(event, context);
  };

const secondMiddleware =
  <TResult>() =>
  (handler: Lambda<TResult>): Lambda<TResult> =>
  async (event, context) => {
    console.log("secondMiddleware");
    return await handler(event, context);
  };

const applyMiddleware = compose(firstMiddleware(), secondMiddleware());
```

The issue is that for all implementations of `compose` I've seen, when I apply the middleware to my handler which has closed over the TResult type, I lose the TResult type.

```js
const handler: Lambda<string> = (event, context) => Promise.resolve("result");

// wrappedHandler is typed as: const wrappedHandler: Lambda<unknown>, not Lambda<string>
const wrappedHandler = applyMiddleware(handler);
```

Is an implementation of `compose` that does what I'm trying to achieve possible, or is this a limitation of typescript.

Comment: Try this implementation of compose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057205/typescript-reduce-an-array-of-function/67760188#67760188 . The problem is in `compose(firstMiddleware(), secondMiddleware())` . TS is unable to preserve/infer/figure out generic parameter of `firstMiddleware` since you called it without it. In order to infer th return type of `applyMiffleware` you should call `compose` as follow: `const applyMiddleware = compose(firstMiddleware<string>(), secondMiddleware<string>());`

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is that the middleware is completely generic and does not care about TResult. TResult is unknown at the point that we compose the middleware together as the middleware can wrap any type of lambda (Lambda<string> or Lambda<number> for instant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know what you think about this:

```js
type Foo = typeof foo
type Bar = typeof bar
type Baz = typeof baz


type Fn = (a: any) => any

type Head<T extends any[]> =
    T extends [infer H, ...infer _]
    ? H
    : never;

type Last<T extends any[]> =
    T extends [infer _]
    ? never : T extends [...infer _, infer Tl]
    ? Tl
    : never;
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541275/typescript-check-for-the-any-type
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N;
type IsAny<T> = IfAny<T, true, never>;

type HandleAny<T extends Fn, U> =
    IsAny<Head<Parameters<T>>> extends true ?
    (a: U) => ReturnType<T>
    : T

type Allowed<
    T extends Fn[],
    Cache extends Fn[] = []
    > =
    T extends []
    ? Cache
    : T extends [infer Lst]
    ? Lst extends Fn
    ? Allowed<[], [...Cache, Lst]> : never
    : T extends [infer Fst, ...infer Lst]
    ? Fst extends Fn
    ? Lst extends Fn[]
    ? Head<Lst> extends Fn
    ? Head<Parameters<Fst>> extends ReturnType<Head<Lst>>
    ? Allowed<Lst, [...Cache, HandleAny<Fst, ReturnType<Head<Lst>>>]>
    : never
    : never
    : never
    : never
    : never;

type LastParameterOf<T extends Fn[]> =
    Last<T> extends Fn
    ? Head<Parameters<Last<T>>>
    : never

type Return<T extends Fn[]> =
    Head<T> extends Fn
    ? ReturnType<Head<T>>
    : never


function compose<T extends Fn, Fns extends T[], Allow extends {
    0: [never],
    1: [LastParameterOf<Fns>]
}[Allowed<Fns> extends never ? 0 : 1]>
    (...args: [...Fns] & Allowed<Fns>): (...data: Allow) => Return<Fns>

function compose<
    T extends Fn,
    Fns extends T[], Allow extends unknown[]
>(...args: [...Fns]) {
    return (...data: Allow) =>
        args.reduceRight((acc, elem) => elem(acc), data)
}

const foo = (arg: 1 | 2) => [1, 2, 3]
const bar = (arg: string) => arg.length > 10 ? 1 : 2
const baz = (arg: number[]) => 'hello'

/**
 * Ok, but you need explicitly add allowed type
 */
const check = compose((a: string) => a, baz)([1, 2, 3]) // [number]

/**
 * Errors
 */
// error because no type
const check_ = compose((a) => a, baz)([1, 2, 3])
// error because `a` expected to be string instead of number
const check__ = compose((a: number) => a, baz)([1, 2, 3])

interface APIGatewayProxyEventV2 {
    body: string;
}

interface Context {
    awsRequestId: string;
}

type APIGatewayProxyResultV2<T = never> = string | T;

type Lambda<TResult = any> = (
    event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2,
    context: Context
) => Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2<TResult>>;

const firstMiddleware =
    <TResult,>() =>
        (handler: Lambda<TResult>): Lambda<TResult> =>
            async (event, context) => {
                console.log("firstMiddleware");
                return await handler(event, context);
            };

const secondMiddleware =
    <TResult,>() =>
        (handler: Lambda<TResult>): Lambda<TResult> =>
            async (event, context) => {
                console.log("secondMiddleware");
                return await handler(event, context);
            };

const applyMiddleware = <T,>(handler: Lambda<T>) => compose(firstMiddleware<T>(), secondMiddleware<T>())(handler);

const handler: Lambda<string> = (event, context) => Promise.resolve("result");

const wrappedHandler = applyMiddleware(handler) // Lambda<string>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKpJwGZQwgUG6AIQEMAnZVcCTKAIzPyqhIC8KCb6XceDYA7CgApiALijF%20IAJTIAfBKm8mACQjEAJgB4AKlAgAPYBH4aAzopABtALoKkuKE6h7Dx0xasBLfhgjkVABooADownz9yAH0bR2cAfigVOKdxfggAN38AbmVIKAAZYjNgXX0jE3NLW3sUl3L3Ku9ffygYusT0rPJxVwqPKCswkIjWqODR8h0AG1jnKESZurTMnNwAenWoAGNSCA0vYAsAczgIC2BEAAtgYDAzUU2S4m2AazhujGm4AHcQ7bgAFt1gBHACu52AXjg-DM6wArIiACwARgATAB2eHrAhmXZeMDAAC02yuEDeRJwpCJwDJRMkIBpVEY%20QAkhgAIJSXTBACawQAcvYoAAGBqVCxCFFQABkLlkiV5UHEAtyfFZZi5IF0wvZWp5qFIEOCXX8clyLOgKkkGmmEH1fUaFhg-GCAFVavMNfq1JotAAFMjEQEQYykMw6uQKNwSw0QhZ1ETiN2yJAKABKobBpH4OioOuWLjy0A502%20P32WjqjtjLtsgTqAGEXmTxQM6zYKLY6p7nDWBt35olm6SIIX%2001JoUSnMEtPgG2qi6OlBS%20XK-XBsMR2TggUZwoVt1x4vPFOYCVgsMp-vgLOnIkLwuY%203%20Cvb6eBIO577tLfo-0S5vkOSTqNogakMGob%20BGT5Rp%20mbANmub5r%20Wj-nIK5rr8la3sEQxhDuEDBNaph2vqT7BIhyF5pAWhoRhch2IWpqkCxqxsfMR7%20Oxx5cVArEWnwRQlBBUFhgA8hgZQvkBNTIHUImlDoAFOgIK5oWJIZhhGSmRph-GscWUDUTmMmAc6-DyQ48xoSpn7LiBpkoXRdlRrxPE8BgYL8NsUIwjsQJgHAZgQOZakusELoWLJFg6Ju2E-J%20ADedQiuIVisTYDbzCiGVKVp0GkFJWjRUxuAAL5WIllZlZ%20rELKKypQCizHzEIwxkMcDxbmE0WdnKNXaGV0jiB1YQaMQwBiKuZa-KmGZZmZZVeT5fnQoIAKAsFoVVvME6WTlzjRZ%208XZbN5afj5rz8L8VmxHI40hF1PUESE-WyKl8x7EhOZQE9k3TeIiULXU8wvSEewaGC2wQOmXjHDcQgiNs2zBBAdqAgt%20iYyj2zSMEgPENIlU8ACsILjgiAoCIpDHOI0oAD5QGi2NWCiwRosEADMsTkyUdBkMIXXiCUpA%20Mc2NdSEdr8MctJQAoKJiok0riGiuD8wuXDC3TaRgoCtD%20LY2MAORknNps8OsABUNuODbUASa8wS0GCC4gHAYICRA%20zlGA0xeNshzTCAEgaBoEhzRWkcEA76yazCAujm8FBbTtEDIzNYsS1LrvECw0hCOznM8zYsibIM-AG0bpCxBsdsO1AACipCkHA4bxxsWz%20O35BG9sxBgqFAmIHHWs7GSbxRGnQUhZnIh54LhfFxzLNlyTle9x3dDkkPI8AAbEAf-vksYseIEbUA53LUA%20CUYFQDQ1eGzxE8p68UQzyg6fz1n%20uv1IEvLgRcS7rygLzEmuAfBhgwC8Es-pWQAHEpoQB%20MQEA-p24GBAM3LI-BgAADU0RQC%20s4WgcANAgFFsAcWctcgVR4DA-wcDYZQEbDCYwRhSF1GID8MwmZwSQlZBoGhdDjgMOMhyRBKDjDoMwdgkAmYzBgmmEQtEZQUCsWFDfY4UBmY6CEkwIohtJq6GUaohcKAGTCiEHUVYBDgYyNQfIrBcAcF4JMOoo6ThyZcOAOIDhBC3C4Gxm4wEXhdrSOQS4jBbicEWLUcQ8x5xLFRgtBPDAXhwzAAALJeAjnadBewFLzBSSotRgRHqg3mO1K4No7SkHECY2gZidCJOAHIUahRgytOIOUtJ8gwa1KcMUEAvl-oOOAMEPxbhsZkJGYswKsI4B2hlnAY4QgABEWScn5MKWgsgEAtnSFyEspZP1kISHQYcKA9SyL%20CEFMmZnC5lnPOU4CqGSk4LlCuTDQ%20zbSHJKTZZwAzKnVKGUsoQ9ygVNJ6aY-p7TUlqK6c03pbSOn2AMh8iQZhxnbEmfg6Zyz-HzOGR8-mqyIDrM2Vsv5MIAUFKBcU45pyKXnMuX9PhxBbmwsaU84lLzglGHZbiqAXyyY-IkGAAOIBAVFKORQHkj1%20X%20HRYinU2Nf6hSELskoCrgVhRUkIAm19ySMsNaynUpqi5qqAd8imdyGnqoRX0rQujbHPNJXM%20QUBwmRJpXsMwqysjbODZYk5FpK4-EgrK-YpE4V3wuFQSOxRxAT1jcQeNGhE2NI1e666t0fj8DkCaOAC4WlmM9YnJ1Wac15taNY2VocrVHJhS6h1uAgA)

Since middlewares are generic we can infer generic parameter from handler and pass it to the middlewares.