# How can I strongly type a composed mixin?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I'm attempting to use functional composition to add behaviors to an object with mixins:

```
const pipe = (...funcs: ((...args: any[]) => any)[]) => (initial: any) => funcs.reduce((object, fn) => fn(object), initial);

  const speakMixin = <T,>(obj: T): T & { speak: () => void } => ({
    ...obj,
    speak: () => console.log("I can speak!")
  });

  const flyMixin = <T,>(obj: T): T & { fly: () => void } => ({
    ...obj,
    fly: () => console.log("i'm flying")
  });

  const chain = pipe(speakMixin, flyMixin);
  const mixed = chain({});

  mixed.fly(); // fly member is typed to any
```

Is there a better way to type my `pipe` function so that I get type safety on objects to which I have applied mixins?

Comment: It’s definitely possible but it’s not pretty. You can look at the types for lodash flow function to see how it can be done. It’s similar to how Promise.all is typed.

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057205/typescript-reduce-an-array-of-function/67760188#67760188 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68800808/can-you-write-a-compose-method-that-infer-types-correctly-if-the-innermost-fun/68801798#68801798 . Also please see my article https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose

Answer (score 2):

Digging deeper into this question I have realized, that my previous typings of `compose/pipeline` function are not helpful in this case.

If you have a set of such kind of functions, I think you can type them in this way:

```js
type Fn = (arg: any) => any

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

const pipe =
  <T extends Fn, Fns extends T[]>(...fns: [...Fns]) =>
    <Data extends Record<string, unknown>>(data: Data) =>
      fns.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), data) as Data & UnionToIntersection<ReturnType<Fns[number]>>;

const speakMixin = <T,>(obj: T) => ({
  ...obj,
  speak: () => console.log("I can speak!")
});

const flyMixin = <T,>(obj: T) => ({
  ...obj,
  fly: () => console.log("i'm flying")
});


// const check: {
//     age: number;
// } & {
//     fly: () => void;
// } & {
//     speak: () => void;
// }
const check = pipe(flyMixin, speakMixin)({ age: 42 })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFAQwE4HMBcU1wgCUSAfPoQFCUD0NUAxhhACYCWwAzlFgPYTdgvKAAtgwMJxx1OwNAwDWvAG4QMAMwA2vAO4A6BrwC2NNDQCsABgDMAdnMAmABwA2SqEhQAqnDa84ACq8AJJwwGqcEAzAfnAAPF7kyCheUBAAHuFwLNwEIFAA-KgKeF4kiOTKvGwsUHhwEKoYJBlZOaiUUFAlUGxw6mpQwZTlldUsnYVDk-WNagDc1IZwslBgbJ6Ik3EBaZkQ2dzwADSwK3tt3AEA2gC6pCh6T+oreNdPevCct6OTXXEAETQcguB3aACUorwMCw4rIMH0sKcAK5wBRwXRwUgPFjAtB4IFyX5dElQF6cPTMFjIhgQFDoBgMU4vUZkuAMhhEU64on4biEtBQABk3l8-iCoXCGEi0VicUhwGRGEC4AgcS+1zgyKMACM1PdSItKMtVpxIGgFABZNjpPpIKA7Y4PXg6gBWeACrJQAG9Jh8Xa7jpMzRALXgUKyTbxNBA9NosCgAETBRgEKAhi0AQkTREoAF8iEaTcAyZoQNbbQhkI7nW6PV7fV1-W6g10tCBw5H-Jxo7H40m2AByIylkCInP5wvUWj0YuMERRHq+uik-BYCD1bV6jCLFd54VQZf0UntztkKBVGq7+j7kVH1cZnoR8+XljXqB543dksMBeKe3rJAKDthWfSnI+oFwEQPprhuUAACwOB+uaUEAA)

List of related questions: [ [typing pipe function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319258/how-to-type-pipe-function-using-variadic-tuple-types-in-typescript-4), [typing pipe function 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057205/typescript-reduce-an-array-of-function/67760188#67760188), [typing compose function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68800808/can-you-write-a-compose-method-that-infer-types-correctly-if-the-innermost-fun/68801798#68801798), [my article](https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose) ]