# How to get type from the return of a function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make a pseudo pipeline in typscript. The idea is that I would have a function that returns me an object. Then I would pass this object to other functions that can process this object.

The function signature would be something like this:

```js
type FirstFunc<T> = () => T;
type Pipeline<T> = ((obj: T) => T)[]

const objPipeLine<T> = (firstFunc: FirstFunc<T>, pipeline: Pipeline<T>): T
```

But I don't want to provide the generic to this function. I want it to know what type of object the first function would return and use it as my T generic. Something like an implicit typing, the functions in the Pipeline should only accept parameters matching the kind of object my first function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this syntax is wrong: `const objPipeLine<T>`.

If you want to infer function argument, you should do `const objPipeLine=<T>()=>{}`.

Just put generic right after `equal` sign.

Consider this example:

```js
type FirstFunc<T> = () => T;
type Pipeline<T> = ((obj: T) => T)[]

const objPipeLine = <Return,>(firstFunc: FirstFunc<Return>, pipeline: Pipeline<Return>) => {}

const result = objPipeLine(
    () => ({ age: 42 }),
    [(obj) => obj]
)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7BgVwHYGMA8AVAPigF4oAKAShKLwG4AoUSKABTkgBs4MJ8jSyZAPYAjAFYAuKHirEaFANoBdevSxCMKKKLFtIAGW7RSOAEoRgaBBgA0BMgDNEKdNinxkqTLnOXrBGygwdgguHik9UKMzCysMAlkiAG8AX1V1TWAoBAgkNA4s0h1Iwx4yeihK8kTyJKgAQwBzCCkAFgAmKBSKGwqqhWFxGp0VCiA)

I have created `Return` generic and let TS infer it. If you hover your mouse on `obj` in `[(obj) => obj]` you will see that it is inferred as `{age: number}`.

If you are interested in typing `pipeline` function you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/FP-style), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69616906/how-can-i-strongly-type-a-composed-mixin/69627763#69627763) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319258/how-to-type-pipe-function-using-variadic-tuple-types-in-typescript-4/68513136#68513136)

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what I was aiming for. It works perfectly!

Answer (score -2):

That's what typescript is made for, to specify them types, to assign a type to the return type we use ReturnType

```
type some=ReturnType<FirstFunc<T>>
```

Comment: The wording is a bit unclear. "to assign a type to the return type we use ReturnType" should probably say something like "to get the return type of a function, we use `ReturnType`"