# Define type to array behavior

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to crate a type that can hold an array where each element is a function that gets the previous output as an input.
For example, a valid array is:

```
const pipe: SpecialArray = [
    () => string,
    (prev:string) => number,
    (prev:number) => boolean
];
```

An invalid array would be:

```
const pipe: SpecialArray = [
    () => string,
    (prev:number) => number, // <-- Here number should be string
    (prev:number) => boolean
];
```

Is there a way to define such structure in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

I believe no, since `Array` is homogenous, you'll have to define in the form `[(a: string) => number, (b: number) => boolean]`, and you can't really enumerate all (unless a code generator is used).

Comment: My use case is to pass such an array to generate a value. I can't define all possible inputs.

Comment: Is the array-like use case a must? If not, how about a type like `type Pipe<A, B>`, and then combine it?

Comment: Sound good, can you elaborate? What is Pipe<>?

Comment: This?
`type Pipe<A, B, C> = [(input:A) => B, (input:B)=>C] `

Comment: No, I'm referring to something like the [`pipe` function in the fp-ts library](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/function.ts.html#pipe), and I'm assuming that you're doing function composition like `.` in Haskell, which is you don't really care the the middle values, but only the start & end one.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in TypeScript to create standalone type for such kind of array. In order to do that you should create `compose` function, infer each function from arguments and validate it. Please see my [article](https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose) and questions/answers on SO: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319258/how-to-type-pipe-function-using-variadic-tuple-types-in-typescript-4/68513136#68513136) , [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057205/typescript-reduce-an-array-of-function/67760188#67760188), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68800808/can-you-write-a-compose-method-that-infer-types-correctly-if-the-innermost-fun/68801798#68801798).

Also you can check this [compose function](https://github.com/drizzer14/fnts/blob/main/src/compose.ts) in `fnts` lib