# Type definitions for ramda compose function

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm been trying to figure out the correct type definitions for the `compose` function, see the [discussion on github](https://github.com/ramda/types/discussions/31) and the [discussion on discord](https://discord.com/channels/508357248330760243/1057653400046674112/threads/1081578839915905114).

Consider [the example below](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEpwGZQiOAIimRABNlCBuAKBuwFcA7AYxmAibhf0lQFMATAB4MABgA0mAIxSMggHwAKGnByCAXHCXItGaQEo4AXgWZBE1TmladesUdMzLB27swOTZ+XADeVqH4YBiguJQAPe0czbEElbGkIgwNaAF86HiZUeB5wCAEAFX5sk25efKEVNQwAOjJ+bGQGABsYAoglAHJG5uaAI2QWAGtOg0tqmqYYAAslQzgAegW4YWE4GABPMGKWKGAweGB0ZGbA5DINsqZGATIaAyUAbVk4QQBdFLpGVnZOODB9kJRJJnOZlFYEm4ol5nBDNNp3PpouYXFCPMifP41IFgqFtJF0TDYvFEuFkmk6EsylBAmxmpcmAwQH1+FA4AAfODZPZMADmNEyJQB2yKJWM-0BcSstSms0M40wdQaTVa7S6PX6gxGY3uTxe7xSQA) where I've distilled the `compose` and `pipe` type definitions into a concise example.  The definitions work correctly for `pipe`, but not for `compose` despite them being almost identical (only the order of `f1` and `f2` is different).

```js
function compose2<R0, R1, R2>(
  f2: (a: R1) => R2,
  f1: (a: R0) => R1,
): (a: R0) => R2 {
  return (x: R0) => f2(f1(x));
}

const composeTest = compose2(
  R.defaultTo('fallback'),
  R.nth(1) // << typescript is already confused
)([1, 2]);

function pipe2<R0, R1, R2>(
  f1: (a: R0) => R1,
  f2: (a: R1) => R2,
): (a: R0) => R2 {
  return (x: R0) => f2(f1(x));
}

// correctly number | string
const pipeTest = pipe2(
  R.nth(1),
  R.defaultTo('fallback'),
)([1, 2]);
```

What I think this boils down to is that typescript is doing it's inference *in the order of the code* instead of building a type dependency tree and evaluating it in that order. Is this accurate?

Does anyone have an insight into this problem?

Comment: We've had so many Q&A's about typing a pipe/compose function here already. TL;DR it isn't feasible in TypeScript yet. You can probably find the other ones just by searching for them online.

Comment: You can check my [article](https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose) and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057205/typescript-reduce-an-array-of-function/67760188#67760188) and third party [library](https://github.com/drizzer14/fnts)

Comment: See how `fp-ts` defines [pipe](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/function.ts#L651-L689)

Comment: Typescript evaluates the types left-to-right which doesn't play nicely with compose which wants to operator right-to-left

Comment: I will also recommend fp-ts as the cleanest solution for composition that actually works in TS