# Check if type is the unknown type

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to check if a type parameter `T` is in fact the `unknown` type ?

I know it can be done to check for `any` ([solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541672/11153160)), but was wondering about `unknown`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution is this:

```
type IsUnknown<T> = unknown extends T ? true : never
```

However, it also returns `true` for `any`, since that is assignable to any type. If you need to handle that case, borrow the solution for `IsAny` and do this:

```
type IsUnknown<T> = IsAny<T> extends true ? never : unknown extends T ? true : never

type A = IsUnknown<unknown> // true
type B = IsUnknown<any> // never
type C = IsUnknown<never> // never
type D = IsUnknown<string> // never
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZgQQHYgDwBUA0UCa2ByAfFALxQAMUEAHsBEgCYDOUAFAIxQBkU6AlFAD8uKAC4o%20ALAAoUJFhNkadMTLwlGbMABOAVwjYkEAG4RthGTLnQYTAKpIA1kgD2AdyQZVCjSqq16ZigdfSEoI1NtMShdJ1cPfzpGFnQwkOhxCLNLWXBoBFIFB2d3T1iSj2IAeirgvQgrPKgAIULbYvjPAEMUatqs7Ub5AGE2%20zjS1AG%208JNs3PkAETGOyaYdAEskAHMZgZkgA)