# "WithoutUnknowns" type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a generic typescript type that omits any key-value pair from an input type where the value is of type unknown:

```
interface Foo {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  bla: unknown;
  baz: boolean;
}

type T = OmitUnknowns<Foo>;
// should be { foo: string; bar: number; baz: boolean; }
```

Is this possible? I'm struggling to figure it out because it seems like everything `extends unknown` in typescript...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if type is the unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68232762/check-if-type-is-the-unknown-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) to remove the `unknown` properties (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68232762/check-if-type-is-the-unknown-type) for how to test for `unknown`):

```
interface Foo {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
    bla: unknown;
    baz: boolean;
}

type OmitUnknowns<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T as unknown extends T[Key] ? never : Key]: T[Key];
};

type T = OmitUnknowns<Foo>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIyYBcyAzmFKAOYDc+hARnFGSAK4C2T0DhyJgBs4ZDiADWIdAHcQ-ZnABeZJpiEQ483AF9cuMAE8ADigDyXYGACqk6XPIAeACoA+ZAF4cjAgG0A0hCGyKDIEkHoMMjOyHDkyOJSsiDIEAAekCAAJvHOAUEAusgA-MggEABu0MhkgYYFZHl1BQw6DAYmKDFeFla2SQ6OGOiuDAD0Y4QAesW4QA)

Comment: Beautiful, works like a charm! I saw the section about Key remapping via `as` in the typescript docs, but I'm confused - could you explain a bit what the `keyof T as unknown extends T[Key] ? never : Key` does?

Comment: @DeX3 - Basically, it says "For each `Key` in `keyof T`, if `unknown extends T[Key]`, use `never` for the key, otherwise use `Key` for the key." And if you use `never` as a key, the property is completely omitted from the resulting object type. In contrast, if we did `[Key in keyof T]: unknown extends T[Key] ? never : T[Key]` where we always take the key without doing anything to it, but convert the value to `never`, we'd end up with `bla: never` in the resulting object type. Mapping a key to `never` is *really* helpful for pruning object types. :-)