# Intersection to the most restricted type

Tags: typescript

I'm tying to write a helper type that intersects all types in a tuple type but with one logic in mind:

The types that add the most restrictions "win" over the others. The final intersection must be the most-restricted type that can be assigned to every individual type of the tuple.

An example. Let's call that helper type `Join`. Here are some assertions :

```js
Join<[string, any[]]> // string & any[]
Join<[string, number, boolean]> // never (string & number & boolean)
Join<[string, { z: boolean }]> // string & { z: boolean }
Join<[{ x: number }, { y: string }]> // { x: number } & { y: string }
Join<[{ x: number }, { y: string }, { z: boolean }]> // { x: number } & { y: string } & { z: boolean }
Join<[any, { y: string }]> // { y: string }
Join<[any, string]> // string
Join<[unknown, string]> // string
Join<[any, unknown, any, any]> // unknown
Join<[any, any, any]> // any
```

I have no idea where to start. Any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: How would you describe the term "restriction" in context of your question?

Comment: @hakre In the sense of "the least broad union". For example given the tuple `[string, any]`, `any` is assignable to both but is too broad, `string` is what I want.

Comment: And when looking into the unknown, any case, you prefer unknown, because it's not all any? so one type is always fall-through and the hierarchy is any -> unknown -> (string, ...?) -> ...?

Comment: @hakre Yes to both questions !

Comment: well what about the blanks (... and ? parts)? or is the third object GenericValue ? and what is the fourth object and how many objects are in the set?

Comment: @hakre The effect I want is that of a chain of `&`, in a world where `string & any` would be `string` (which is not the case, it's `any`).

Comment: @hakre Everything that's not `any` or `unknown` should be `&`'d together.

Comment: what about `never` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type Elem = any;

type FilterAny<
  Arr extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>,
  Result extends ReadonlyArray<Elem> = []
  > = Arr extends []
  ? Result
  : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
  ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>
  ? IsAny<H> extends true
  ? FilterAny<Tail, Result>
  : FilterAny<Tail, [...Result, H]>
  : never
  : never;

type Join<T extends any[]> =
  FilterAny<T>['length'] extends 0
  ? any
  : UnionToIntersection<FilterAny<T>[number]>

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541275/typescript-check-for-the-any-type
type IsAny<T> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? true : false;


type Result1 = Join<[string, any[]]> // string & any[]
type Result2 = Join<[string, number, boolean]> // never (string & number & boolean)
type Result3 = Join<[string, { z: boolean }]> // string & { z: boolean }
type Result4 = Join<[{ x: number }, { y: string }]> // { x: number } & { y: string }
type Result5 = Join<[{ x: number }, { y: string }, { z: boolean }]> // { x: number } & { y: string } & { z: boolean }
type Result6 = Join<[any, { y: string }]> // { y: string }
type Result7 = Join<[any, string]> // string
type Result8 = Join<[unknown, string]> // string
type Result9 = Join<[any, unknown, any, any]> // unknown
type Result10 = Join<[any, any, any]> // any
```

`FilterAny` iterates over the tuples recursively and removes all `any` from the tuple

`Join` logic:

1. If `FilterAny` returns empty array - return `any`
2. return intersection of union of all array elements

More examples with tuple manipulations you can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/tuples#reduce)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGMCcFMBMEsAuBnUBzA9tViOgBaKIAOyAXCMogIbgDWGAbtJAGYA2GA7gHTgYBbYNWABWAAwBmAOyiATAA4AbAChEAT2LRQAVQB28DHoAqGAJJ7ELZNHCJDegDw6AfKAC8oABQ7Q0AB5WerCo1HrqoAD83nRkugCUHm6MGPCwoHF60MyQiQFBId4qoKCxoPB6rCygZiqJ7smpsMVRNS2Z2SwA3CpqmtoAouzQAh6gYeo9fVqgAGLw7FaQAILhji3LkJB%20gdDBqABK0NSwRuzqm5DU6o5DIy4ANC1HyACuizsFh8eneueX11uwwEbk8AG0ALotUGgS6fPaFSEtaIvd6Idqwrbw-agGAnM4RMEVKrbAASD1APCpxOqxmoCyhJWidIW2MKR3xfwuW0BdxByJqyFWN1JbnyCJwkFe0AF80WLGFjhZ7ApqMWLgxcqWiuVFLBVJ4asQFNJEI1JQ6OQxWRyUw0MwAUqknMY2aFwpDQS0tQq1sYXGCAOTDPRoRD4QMQt2gcQCiYY-QOUwWJY2OwORw%20lZ%20gN6V4CABGLDNvXt2jMQpzY3E0a8AEZQAAyUDGRLRRBS7RxVjUdg2KbTbRGhueJ0VRxgqiQCpoCkTSFm0AgUBTmdN8YeqFl0BGuRjMdOScdmcUvOFlgUgsYDDDMKL5c26peVeh9dnovbZtXm-HPTxQc7tgaKSPuzoTi%20s6gAA3qAABecTfreeigAAvveYAQeuMHwaAiG-qhAFGgALKB45gjB-iZPmH6oRSMHqHEmFoW4y4UVR57bChWGgAxK7Hq%20KGEUBiyiKRh5saA77VChdE8Yx-FoLR0FwQh15Iah6HKZRknUdJ3G8Ux3E4XhYQEduRpKGJE4TLJBkKRpLFgPR8nTgJQlvIs0hWWCNl8a5aCaRB7logo3mvHodB6NwegUhBgUKcFiwAJzeb54WRdFc7hFl6iaelUVcHoiWIHWNajmBPnZRu6g5Zp8YqEAA)

Answer (score 0):

I did some playing around, this will support all your cases expect for one, so you can maybe iterate on that:

```
type IfAny<Test, True, False> = 0 extends (1 & Test) ? True : False


type Join<Arr extends [...any[]]> =  Arr extends [infer A] ? A  : Arr extends [infer A, ...infer Rest]  ? 
IfAny<A, Join<Rest>, A & Join<Rest>> : any
```

The only one not working to your specifications would be

```
type Test = Join<[any, unknown, any, any]> // you want unknown and it is any
```