# Typescript strict check type in conditional types

Tags: typescript

In the following code I want `type A` to be `true`, and not the union of both:

```
type isFalseAndNotAny<T> = T extends false ? 'false' : 'true';

// how do I get here only `true`?
type A = isFalseAndNotAny<any>; 
    
// that's OK we get only `false`    
type B = isFalseAndNotAny<false>;
```

Is there any way in Typescript to do something similar like in Javascript we use the triple equality `===` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need slightly modify your util.

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541275/typescript-check-for-the-any-type
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N;
type IsAny<T> = IfAny<T, true, false>;

type isFalseAndNotAny<T> = T extends false ? IsAny<T> extends false ? 'false' : 'true' : 'true';

// true
type A = isFalseAndNotAny<any>;

// false
type B = isFalseAndNotAny<false>;
```

You need explicitly check if `T` extends `false` and not `any`, it is like `T===false && T!==any`