# Enable noImplicitAny for functions wrapped with useCallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

React's `useCallback` is a wrapper around a function that returns the same type as the input, here's the TS type:

```
function useCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  callback: T,
  deps: DependencyList,
): T;
```

If I don't specify the argument type for the input function, I'd expect `noImplicitAny` to cause an error. However, this doesn't cause an error:

```
const fn = useCallback(arg => {}, []);
```

It's possible to change useCallback's type to this to trigger an error in most cases when the argument's type isn't specified:

```
function useCallback<T extends (...args: never[]) => unknown>(
  callback: T,
  deps: DependencyList,
): T;


const fn = useCallback(arg => arg.toString()); // Property 'toString' does not exist on type 'never'.

const fn = useCallback((arg: number) => arg.toString()); // No errors
```

However, this seems to have issues in some cases. E.g. with default arguments:

```
const fn = useCallback((arg = 0) => arg.toString()); // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Usually, TS infers the type of `arg`. If I manually specify the type of `arg`, then Eslint's `@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types` rule produces an error.

Is there a better type for `useCallback` that addresses these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look on `useCallback` types:

```js
    /**
     * `useCallback` will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the `inputs`
     * has changed.
     *
     * @version 16.8.0
     * @see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback
     */
    // TODO (TypeScript 3.0): <T extends (...args: never[]) => unknown>
    function useCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(callback: T, deps: DependencyList): T;
```

As you might have noticed, `callback` is a subtype of `(...args: any[]) => any`. It means that `any` is explicitly provided for `args`. This is why `noImplicitAny` does not work in this case, because `any` is explicit.
As far as I understood and you have noticed - react team wants to replace current `callback` type with  `(...args: never[]) => unknown`.

This subtype provides `never` type for callback argument.

```js
useCallback((arg) => arg.toString(), []); // error because [arg] is never
```

`arg = 0` does not work in a case of `never` because `never` is a bottom type. You are not allowed to assign any/`any` type to `never`.
Consider this example:

```js
let x: never;
let y: any;

x = y; // error
```

`never` is assignable to everything but not vice versa. Please see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never)

> The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself). Even any isn’t assignable to never.

By `in most cases when the argument's type isn't specified` I assume you want to forbid using `any`. I'm not sure whether react team can provide such restriction, because many people are using `any` during the migration from `js` to `ts`.

If you want to use default parameter, type of argument should be either `any` or has the same type as default parameter. Hence, we have a collision. You want to disallow `any` and at the same type you want to use default parameter.

You are able to override `useCallback` type in this way:

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541275/typescript-check-for-the-any-type
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends 1 & T ? Y : N;
type IsAny<T> = IfAny<T, true, false>;

type ValidateArguments<T extends any[]> = IsAny<
  T[number]
> extends true
  ? 'Custom Error'[] // please provide any type you want
  : T;

type HandleCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = (
  ...args: ValidateArguments<Parameters<T>>
) => ReturnType<T>;

declare module "react" {
  function useCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
    callback: HandleCallback<T>,
    deps: any[]
  ): T;
}

const App = () => {
  const result = useCallback((arg /** "Custom Error" */) => {}, []);
};
```

[Playground](http://import%20React,%20%7B%20useCallback%20%7D%20from%20%27react%27%20%20//%20credits%20goes%20to%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541275/typescript-check-for-the-any-type%20type%20IfAny%3CT,%20Y,%20N%3E%20=%200%20extends%201%20&%20T%20?%20Y%20:%20N;%20type%20IsAny%3CT%3E%20=%20IfAny%3CT,%20true,%20false%3E;%20%20type%20ValidateArguments%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E%20=%20IsAny%3C%20%20%20T%5Bnumber%5D%20%3E%20extends%20true%20%20%20?%20%27Custom%20Error%27%5B%5D%20%20%20:%20T;%20%20type%20HandleCallback%3CT%20extends%20(...args:%20any%5B%5D)%20=%3E%20any%3E%20=%20(%20%20%20...args:%20ValidateArguments%3CParameters%3CT%3E%3E%20)%20=%3E%20ReturnType%3CT%3E;%20%20declare%20module%20%22react%22%20%7B%20%20%20function%20useCallback%3CT%20extends%20(...args:%20any%5B%5D)%20=%3E%20any%3E(%20%20%20%20%20callback:%20HandleCallback%3CT%3E,%20%20%20%20%20deps:%20any%5B%5D%20%20%20):%20T;%20%7D%20%20const%20App%20=%20()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20const%20result%20=%20useCallback((arg%20/**%20%22Custom%20Error%22%20*/)%20=%3E%20%7B%7D,%20%5B%5D);%20%7D;)

Instead `CustomError` you can use any type you want. However, using `<T extends (...args: never[]) => unknown>` might be a better solution than mine.