# How can one determine if a type is void or any

Tags: typescript

How can one determine if a type is either `void` or `any`?

```js
type IsAny = void extends any ? true : false   // true

type IsVoid = any extends void ? true : false  // true
```

Based on the above it's not possible to determine if a type is `void` or if it is `any`.  Is there another way to determine which one of the two it is?

Comment: typescript 4.5.4 reports `type IsVoid = any extends void ? true : false` as `boolean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void` and `any` are not mutually exclusive: a `void` is also an `any`.
You can see it by doing the union betweed them. If they were exclusive, `void` would not disappear to let only `any`:

```js
type T = void | any // any
```

Knowing that, it is normal that your `IsAny` resolves to `true`.

As for your `IsVoid` type, it resolves to `boolean`, which is actually `true | false`. You can see that by changing `true` and `false` by something else like `1` and `2`. You will then get `1 | 2`.

This is because your `any` type could be either `void` or something else that is not `void`. So we don't know if it extends `void` or not.

To know if a type is exactly `any` and nothing more special, or exactly `void` and nothing less special, you can do like this  (inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541672/1774332)):

```js
type IsStrictAny<T> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? T : never;

type A = IsStrictAny<any> // any
type B = IsStrictAny<void> // never

type IsVoid<T> = T extends void ? T : never
type IsNotStrictAny<T> = T extends IsStrictAny<T> ? never : T
type IsStrictVoid<T> = IsVoid<T> & IsNotStrictAny<T>

type C = IsStrictVoid<any> // never
type D = IsStrictVoid<void> // void
```