# Map property of type any/unknown to generic type T

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

If I have...

```
type TypeNonGeneric = { prop1: any, prop2: string };
```

How can I map this to...

```
type TypeGeneric<T> = { prop1: T, prop2: string };
```

I've looked at the docs and it seems that it needs to be a new generic type that would take `TypeNonGeneric` as a parameter, iterate over its keys and if a property type is `any` then it returns a "T" else leaves the type unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `IfAny` utility type from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541275/typescript-check-for-the-any-type). We can then map over the passed type and check for `any` for each property.

```
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N;

type TypeGeneric<O, T> = {
  [K in keyof O]: IfAny<O[K], T, O[K]>
}
```

Let's see an example:

```
type TypeNonGeneric = { prop1: any, prop2: string };

type Result = TypeGeneric<TypeNonGeneric, number>
// type Result = {
//    prop1: number;
//    prop2: string;
// }
```

or if you want to replace `any` with `T`

```
type Result2<T> = TypeGeneric<TypeNonGeneric, T>
// type Result = {
//    prop1: T;
//    prop2: string;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=5&pln=19&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgMwIIDswB4AqAaGBNXAOQD4YBeGABhigA8QoUATAZxgAoBGGAMhkwCUMAPz4YALhiEA3MFCRYmBQHFGUAE4BLAMboA8rkykKAb2AwYAbQDSMTShgBrKGAD2CGHoC6kxKgx6Nl6GuIHWXsTAAL5y8tD8CoSuKKooGjrkMCYwEOquEJySAIZouLn5AEySLCBaKADmMFGycbAASlAsAK4ANiCZStCp6bqDUEkpalrauChdALYARhqRAPSrMODxHd19mWbrFhblBZJzSxqyh0cnVTA1dfVXGzGxW+2dvSAVWMYJQ1MdFhEslhtNDGsNu8YDsvvtgNdjnlTvxnkccsi7g97E8ES8gA)

Comment: I want the type parameter to preserve on the new type. So TypeGeneric wouldn't take a second type parameter, it would add one to the resulting type and prop1 would be type T.

Comment: you can remove `O` from the generic type of `TypeGeneric` and replace it inside the map with `TypeNonGeneric` if you want