# TypeScript: any vs any[] in extends

Tags: typescript

`any` seems to both extend and **not** extend `any[]` i.e. it returns both values `1 | 2`:

```
type Test<T> = T extends any[] ? 1 : 2;
type Result = Test<any>; // 1 | 2
```

Is this correct? And how could I determine the difference between being passed an `any` vs an `Array<any>`?

I am trying to use it in the following example and it's causing unexpected results (not sure if the problems are related):

```
type Push<T, A = []> = [T, ...(A extends any[] ? A : [A])];
type PushTest = Push<5, any>; // [5, ...any[]]
```

I would expect PushTest to be `[5, any]` not `[5, ...any[]]`.
`Push<5, 6>` works (returning `[5, 6]`) and using `unknown` also works, but I haven't been able to get `any` to work.

This is just part of my experimentation to gain a deeper understanding of TS.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please see the answer to the linked question for information.

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate of the linked task where the response was: "any matches anything, so return the union of both branches".

But I would still like to know how to differentiate between any and any[].

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541275/typescript-check-for-the-any-type) shows how to distinguish `any` from other types.  You can also distinguish because, for example, `unknown extends any[]` is *false*,  while `unknown extends any` is *true*