# No compile time error for Typescript type mismatch

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function defined like this:

```js
export async function removeUser(deleteUserId: Types.ObjectId)
```

When I mistakenly called this function and pass a Mongoose object's `id` parameter, which is a string, it triggered a runtime exception further in the code when I tried to use the `.equals()` method which exists on an ObjectId but not on a string:

```js
await removeUser(deleteUser.id);
```

When I corrected this by passing the ObjectId, everything worked fine:

```js
await removeUser(deleteUser._id);
```

My question is, why didn't I get a compile time error from Typescript if the argument is specified as an ObjectId, but a string is being passed?

Edit: I see that the `.id` is defined as `any`, not as a `string`.  I suspect that will factor into the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see that the .id is defined as any, not as a string.

Values of type `any` allow assignment to *any* type.

```
const n: number =  'string' as any // fine
```

It's an escape hatch from the type system. So `any` is not typesafe and should be avoided at all costs.

[See Documentation:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any)

> The compiler effectively treats any as “please turn off type checking for this thing”. It is similar to putting an @ts-ignore comment around every usage of the variable.

Comment: `any` comes from the library, mongoose. Mongoose is questionably designed and has both `id` (for private use) and `_id` (for your use).

Comment: @vera. Well that sucks. Good to know!

Answer (score 2):

Yep, if we can somehow [check for any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541275/typescript-check-for-the-any-type), then we can make sure that values of type `any` cannot be passed:

```
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N;

export async function removeUser<Id extends Types.ObjectId>(deleteUserId: IfAny<Id, never, Id>) {
```

So if we pass in `any`, the type of `deleteUserId` will turn into `never`:

```
await removeUser(deleteUser.id);  // error, type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'
await removeUser(deleteUser._id); // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOxj6N)

Answer (score 2):

Typescript types exist only in compile time, not in runtime.
Therefore, Typescript type system is not sound -- it cannot guarantee you that if your program compiles, it will not throw any error in runtime.

Back to your question, if a variable type is `any`, you can do anything with it, and Typescript will not even blink. You should use `any` type with an **extreme** caution.

For example, if you have a variable `obj` of type `any`:

- You could assign `obj` to any other variable (except of type `never`)
- You could access any fields on `obj` e.g. `obj.a.b.c.d`
- You could pass it to any function, in particular that expecting `string`

[Code example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAgNgTwIIQgUwA6xgDmAciALYBGOATgBQCGAXImBdTQJSIDeAvgCgBOAB544NKIgYBnNJEShIsBIgAmcAMpxyOKAAsYxOnEoArFgzBpOPAYkQB6R4gCSiCFfVxEBmDKZ7DwQZKQZEAF5kcwA6cIAqaLMYygBuIOc3Dy8GFBkfDV9DAKCIELgUHBiUOCITWIYUmIgYtU50h0yrNSzPJE8UFGQwdCxcAiNSdlpEAHcYAySg1ExsfEIpqlp6s3aBQQFMyhApOGBgkBoZHCL-C5Qe4AYYIaNEGnBYXUCNbV0-YwAIgAjAAmADMgL2vx0ekMxh4rAY30QgIAUnB9GBAYg+O0gA):

```
function onlyAcceptingNumber(a: number) {}

export async function doSomething(obj: any){
  // I can do this:
  const a = obj.a * obj.b;
  // I can also do this:
  console.log(obj.a.b.c.d);
  // and I can call onlyAcceptingNumber with obj
  onlyAcceptingNumber(obj);
}

// but of course this could fail in runtime:
doSomething("123");
doSomething({ name: "John" });
```

In the example above, the `doSomething` function would compile, and both calls to it would compile, but of course if we run everything, it would fail in runtime.

To battle this, you can use e.g. [ESLint's no-explicit-any](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any/) rule, and in general only use `any` as a last resort

Comment: See my comment under [Alex Wayne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75101150/18244921). They didn't choose for that `any` to be there. It's questionable library design.

Comment: Hi @vera. 
I was suspecting it too. However, it wasn't clear from the description for me (since they mentioned about typing of `deleteUser.id` and NOT about typing of `Types.ObjectId`, so I guessed that `deleteUser.id` is typed as `any` as well :)
Could've written the answer either way
However, I still hope that my answer would be helpful for the author, since it provides a lot of context