# Typescript generic type but not string or any

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a generic function that looks like this:

```
private getItem<T>(identifier: string): T {...}
```

Now I want to change this, so that the return type can be any object or array, but not any and also not string. I'm unsure how to achieve that.

Comment: Take a look at [Generic Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disallow the use of `any`, you'll need a little more magic. Using a type from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541275/typescript-check-for-the-any-type) to check for `any`, we can then use something like

```
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N; 

declare function foo<T extends IfAny<T, never, object>>(): T;
```

If `T` is `any`, then the constraint is `never`, otherwise, the constraint is `object`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZgQQHYgDwBUA0UCa2ByAfFALxQAMUEAHsBEgCYDOUAFAIxQBkU6AlFAD8uKAC4o+ANxQAsACh5DCAGMANgEMATtDgBXJMuABLAPZIocEyYxVa9ZrEQoM2JBABuETdhMAjAFYqwISErHzi6JLy8pbWTMCaRkgA5qF8UXKxqADeAL5pGVkA2gC6BTFWqOooBVAA9HVirEA)

Answer (score 0):

`T extends object` can be use for objects and arrays, but not primitives and any:

```
private getItem<T extends object>(identifier: string): T {...}
```

Comment: This does not protect against `any`: https://tsplay.dev/Wvq8Qm

Comment: you got that right