# Better way to check for Array<any> type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-conditional-types

My root problem is following, I need to detect that a type is `Array<any>` (not any other Array type).

I can detect this with 2 combined conditions : `T extends Array<any>` and  `Array<any> extends`

How could I write a conditional type without having to resort to a double ternary like following:

```
type foo<T> = T extends Array<any> ? Array<any> extends T ? T : 'not any array' : 'not any array';
```

Comment: Why do you need id to be "fixed"  `Array<any> <= T <= Array<any>`?

Comment: I need to handle a case with `Exclude<T, string[]>` but `Exclude<Array<any>, string[]> = never`.

Comment: Please show the use case, seems like XY problem to me

Comment: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2MoQDYaYBmAlgOYA8AKgHxwC8cA2lQD4DOOJmZTAuq0wBXALYAjYFH58A3ACg5oSLATJUAcWAwq1OowCiIAMZ4hAE2DUANHE5RuvAcPGT+NeQqQo4RCBAZwmtoUAIJQUACGiBQA3gC+NO5yAPTJcOkAegD8nmpwYhFQAUE6YZHREZiIifKp6XDZckA). But please assume I know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that works using only 1 conditional type, borrowing the trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541672/18244921):

```
type foo<T> = [1[] & T, any[]] extends [0[], T] ? T : "not any array";
```

There's two checks going on here: one two check for `any[]`, and the other two disallow `never[]`. To check for `any[]`, we're using the same principle as the linked answer: `any` allows us to do some crazy things, like assigning `1[]` to `0[]`. This however, also allows `never[]` to slip by.

To address `never[]`, we use another check. Because `never` is the bottom type, nothing is assignable to it,. This means that checking if `any[]` is assignable to `T` is all we need.

Example tests:

```
type T01 = foo<any[]>
//   ^? any[]
type T02 = foo<never[]>
//   ^? "not any array"
type T03 = foo<number[]>
//   ^? "not any array"
type T04 = foo<{ bar: any }>
//   ^? "not any array"
type T05 = foo<{ 1: any }>;
//   ^? "not any array"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAZg9nAPAFQHxQLxQNoEZsC6UAZFMgDRQCGAdiIURAB7AQ0AmAzjgAyGXIiAfjJQAXFABENOMGp1qAJ0VUQkgNwAoTaEhkeuTLASJa9Aqk0B6K1DsA9Idt3RkPAExH4SGhABuEIqEljZ2UI7O4K48AMxeJjQArgC2AEaBwda2Dk46UfoALPFIAN5QqVSKEmZQAL4h2eG5LvoArMWIZbjVCvVaoTlAA)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it is possible to do what I *assume* you want to do (please correct me in comments if needed)

```
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N;
type IfAnyArray<T, Y, N> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer V> ? IfAny<V, Y, N> : N;
type IsAnyArray<T> = IfAnyArray<T, 'is any[]', 'is not any[]'>


type test_fooz = IsAnyArray<(number | string)[]>
//   ^?
type test_foo0 = IsAnyArray<number[] | string[]>
//   ^?
type test_foo1 = IsAnyArray<string[]>
//   ^?
type test_foo2 = IsAnyArray<any[]>
//   ^?
type test_foo3 = IsAnyArray<readonly string[]>
//   ^?
type test_foo4 = IsAnyArray<readonly any[]>
//   ^?
type test_foo5 = IsAnyArray<MyArray<string>>
//   ^?
type test_foo6 = IsAnyArray<MyArray<any>>
//   ^?
type test_excb = IsAnyArray<(string & {brand: 'myBrand'})[]>
//   ^?
type test_excB = IsAnyArray<(string & {brand?: 'myBrand'})[]>
//   ^?


class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    x!: number;
}
```

And this is if you want `Exclude`:

```
type ExcludeArrayOf<T, E> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer V extends E> ? IfAny<V, T, never> : T;
 
type test_excz = ExcludeArrayOf<(number | string)[], string>
//   ^?
type test_exc0 = ExcludeArrayOf<number[] | string[], string>
//   ^?
type test_exc1 = ExcludeArrayOf<string[], string>
//   ^?
type test_exc2 = ExcludeArrayOf<any[], string>
//   ^?
type test_exc3 = ExcludeArrayOf<readonly string[], string>
//   ^?
type test_exc4 = ExcludeArrayOf<readonly any[], string>
//   ^?
type test_exc5 = ExcludeArrayOf<MyArray<string>, string>
//   ^?
type test_exc6 = ExcludeArrayOf<MyArray<any>, string>
//   ^?
type test_excb = ExcludeArrayOf<(string & {brand: 'myBrand'})[], string>
//   ^?
type test_excB = ExcludeArrayOf<(string & {brand?: 'myBrand'})[], string>
//   ^?
```

Comment: This is an insane trick...

Comment: @BenWainwright you don't have to remember tricks, you only need to remember they exist (to google them)

Comment: At least link to the respective [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541275/typescript-check-for-the-any-type)...