# Disallow call with any if generic is specified

Tags: typescript, generics

I've tried to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928360/4928642) to disallow call of generic function with second type equal to `any`.

Following construction works until the first generic parameter is explicitely specified:

```
 declare function f<V = any, A extends ISmth = ISmth>(a: IfAny<A, never, A>): V;
```

In case that I need `V` to be first parameter and to be optional (it's return type and can't be inferred - it should iether be specified explicitely or be any), how can I fix the code?

I've tried to change default value, but it breakes any calls with explicit first type:

```
declare function g<V = any, A extends ISmth = any>(a: IfAny<A, never, A>): V;
```

[Full code:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ISmth%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20IfAny%3CT%2C%20Y%2C%20N%3E%20%3D%200%20extends%20(1%20%26%20T)%20%3F%20Y%20%3A%20N%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20f%3CV%20%3D%20any%2C%20A%20extends%20ISmth%20%3D%20ISmth%3E(a%3A%20IfAny%3CA%2C%20never%2C%20A%3E)%3A%20V%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20g%3CV%20%3D%20any%2C%20A%20extends%20ISmth%20%3D%20any%3E(a%3A%20IfAny%3CA%2C%20never%2C%20A%3E)%3A%20V%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20x%3A%20ISmth%2C%20y%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Af(x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine%0D%0Af(y)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'any'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'never'.%0D%0A%0D%0Af%3Cstring%3E(x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine%0D%0Af%3Cstring%3E(y)%3B%20%2F%2F%20BAD%3A%20Should%20be%20an%20error%2C%20but%20compiles%0D%0A%0D%0Ag(x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine%0D%0Ag(y)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'any'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'never'.%0D%0A%0D%0Ag%3Cstring%3E(x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20BAD%3A%20Should%20NOT%20be%20an%20error%0D%0Ag%3Cstring%3E(y)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'any'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'never'.)

```
interface ISmth { x: number; }

type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N;

declare function f<V = any, A extends ISmth = ISmth>(a: IfAny<A, never, A>): V;
declare function g<V = any, A extends ISmth = any>(a: IfAny<A, never, A>): V;

declare var x: ISmth, y: any;

f(x); // Fine
f(y); // Fine: Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

f<string>(x); // Fine
f<string>(y); // BAD: Should be an error, but compiles

g(x); // Fine
g(y); // Fine: Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

g<string>(x); // BAD: Should NOT be an error
g<string>(y); // Fine: Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's currently no [partial type argument inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) in TypeScript, so this won't work for you.  Workarounds are to make a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function where you manually specify one type parameter and return a function whose type parameter is inferred:

```
declare const fCurry: <V = any>() => 
  <A extends ISmth = ISmth>(a: IfAny<A, never, A>) => V;
fCurry()(x); // no error
fCurry()(y); // error
fCurry<string>()(x); // no error
fCurry<string>()(y); // error
```

Or you make a function that takes a dummy argument for the type parameter you wish to manually specify... it can be `null` at runtime but you use a type assertion to let the compiler know what type you mean:

```
declare function fDummy<V = any, A extends ISmth = ISmth>(
  a: IfAny<A, never, A>, 
  dummy?: V
): V;
fDummy(x); // no error
fDummy(y); // error
fDummy(x, null! as string); // no error
fDummy(y, null! as string); // error
```

Neither way is perfect, but they have the desired behavior.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!