# Different result from a conditional type when used directly vs with generic

Tags: typescript

While experimenting for a type `isStrictlyAny` per [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61624719/how-to-conditionally-detect-the-any-type-in-typescript), I arrived at an expression:

```
type IsStrictlyAny<T> = (T extends never ? true : false) extends false ? false : true;
```

which when used then produces:

```
type t1 = IsStrictlyAny<any>;     // true
type t2 = IsStrictlyAny<unknown>; // false
type t3 = IsStrictlyAny<string>;  // false
type t4 = IsStrictlyAny<never>;   // false!
```

This makes sense mostly. But for the last case I noted that "manually" expanding it like so:

```
type t5 = (never extends never ? true : false) extends false ? false : true; // true!!!
```

is `true`, contradicting the above.

Why is this?

---

[Link to playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=9&ssc=88&pln=1&pc=1#code/LAKALgngDgpgBASQM4GUwCcCWBjMAbCAQQDsIAeAFQD44BeOACgrhgA8wZiATJOYmAG4x0cAPxwMAV3gAuOADMAhniQwAlC3aceC5arG6VsiemkBuUKEiwJARjqJUGHPiKkyi0lTNxfvgPT%20JtJW0PBgAEwOyGhYuAQk5JLEANbEAPYA7sTecIGGqqE2YADM0U5xrolkSM7EAOa5eUFKRkXhACzlsS4J7vxC6E3NBTAAhJbgYRIArA4MA8KaHNy8iyLiUsatqhpsKzo78OJHcHJbPvkUpuNjEyBAA)

Comment: Your "manual" expansion is no longer a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  See [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types) for more information.

Comment: @jcalz I am beginning to understand. But here, the type parameter is just `never`, which is not a union. There is nothing to distribute over, so I still don't see how the expanded version differs. In that linked question, I visualize it expanding as `("a" extends B ? never : "a") | ( "b" extends B ? never : "b" ) | ...` and I see why it works, but I cannot do the same here...

Comment: Get ready for your mind to be blown... `never` is treated as [*the empty union*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182#issuecomment-379094672).  So given `F<T> = T extends X ? Y : Z`, `F<never>` will always be `never`.  This is consistent since a distributive conditional type satisfies `F<A | B> = F<A> | F<B>` and thus `F<A | never> = F<A> | F<never>` meaning `F<A> = F<A> | F<never>` for all distributive `F` and for all `A`, so that means `F<never>` should be `never`.

Comment: @jcalz You know, when I said there was "*nothing* to distribute over", this isn't what I had in mind... Thanks, this clicked for me, I see it now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of TypeScript's [distributed conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), combined with the fact that `never` is treated as an empty union.

When using a naked conditional type, as you do here, TypeScript will distribute the condition onto each part of the type, and the result will be the union of each part *after the condition is applied*. Since `never` is just a union of 0 parts, the union of each part after the condition is applied *is still just an empty union*, aka `never`.

Put briefly, *for **any** distributed conditional type* `DCT<T>`, `DCT<never>` is `never`.

Thus, for the final case of your example, the result of `T extends never ? true : false` *is neither* `true` *nor* `false`, but `never`, which makes the final expression:

```
never extends false ? false : true
```

and since `never` extends `false` (and everything else), the result of this is `false`.