# Why does unknown not extend any[]

Tags: typescript

Why does this unknown definitely not extend any[]?

In the code below `any` returns `boolean` as it could be either, however `unknown` doesn't do the same, why is that?

```js
type IsAnyArray1 = unknown extends any[] ? true : false // false
type IsAnyArray2 = any extends any[] ? true : false // boolean
```

Comment: I would put the question back on you. Why do you think `unknown` should extend `any[]`? Why do you think every `unknown` value should be able to be automatically treated as an array?

Comment: The real question here shouldn't be "why doesn't `unknown` extend `any[]`", because you cannot assign a value of type `unknown` to a variable of type `any[]`; `unknown` is absolutely not a subtype of `any[]`.  On the other hand, `any` is considered to be (unsoundly) both a subtype and supertype of every type, so `any extends any[]` is always true (you can always assign a value of type `any` to a variable of type `any[]`).  No, the real question is: why does `IsAnyArray2` return `boolean` instead of `true`? If you understand and agree, I can look at answering that. Let me know.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo - I don't think it SHOULD extend `any[]` only that it MAY extend `any[]` - i.e. it should be the same as `any` which could be any value and so returns boolean.  Unknown leaves me confused and makes my head hurt!

Comment: @jcalz - that's the most understandable response I've seen to this question.  These things would make more sense to me if as you pointed out `any extends any[]` always returned `true` not `boolean`

Comment: `any` is intentionally an unsafe mess of a type. That's the point of it. Trying to apply good programming practices or actual type theory to it will fail, for the simple reason that it is, and has always been, a backdoor to *fight* the type checker, and that's by design.

Comment: The question "why does `any extends XXX ? true : false` return `boolean` instead of `true`" was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68754652/2887218); do you agree that this question is essentially a duplicate of that one (since the inconsistency here is with `any` and not `unknown`)?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz - Most people understand `unknown` to be "the type-safe counterpart of any" - so one would reasonably expect `unknown` and `any` to behave in similar manners, however as this question shows they don't.  Likely what's required is an authoritative answer clarifying the reasons for this divergence.

Comment: Still seems like a duplicate of the other question which also tests `any` vs `unknown`.  But I would expect the "type safe counterpart of `any`" to behave *differently* from `any` precisely because of the difference in type safety. Are you saying you want an answer that explains all the ways in which `any` and `unknown` are the same or different? That would be quite a long answer and isn't directly asked for in the question. The only deviation here is with `any`.  `(any[] | string) extends any[] ? true : false` is `false`. `object extends any[] ? true : false` is `false`.

Comment: So either this question is really about why `any extends any[] ? true : false` is `boolean` instead of `false`, in which case it's a duplicate... or this question is really about why `unknown extends any[] ? true : false` is `false`, in which case `any` is a red herring because it's the only type that behaves differently.  I can write up an answer to that, but the existing answer here is essentially answering the former (without explaining why `any` is a red herring here).  I'm still open to being persuaded otherwise, but so far I'm leaning toward closing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is your question itself.  When you say that `A extends B ? true : false`, it will be `true` if and only if `A` is assignable to `B` and `false` otherwise.  Now, let's now look at your question again:

> Why does this unknown definitely not extend any[]?

`unknown` is a type that is explicitly named for forcing you as a developer to not take any guarantees on the shape of the data.  Therefore, you cannot assign `unknown` to anything except `any` and `unknown`.  You are instead supposed to get the shape of the data by inferring it via checks (if statements like `typeof foo === "string"`) or direct casts (`foo as boolean`).

Therefore, when you ask why does `unknown` not extend `any[]` you are asking why is `unknown` not assignable to `any[]`.  The reason for this is because when you say that `unknown` is assignable to `any[]` then you are making an unsafe guarantee that the data is in fact an array.  The fact that the item within the array is `any` does not matter because you are still saying that the data should have all of the methods and index signatures of the array type.  I hope this helps clear things up for you/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, I remain confused: `unknown` can be any type, and one has to determine its type before using or casting it as you point out.  However, an `unknown` type could in fact be of type `any[]` - so how come the compiler is so sure it is definitely not of type `any[]` - the way it handles `any` seems more consistent.  I.e. an unknown type could, or could not be of type any[] - which is the way `any` handles it.

Comment: @TrevTheDev `unknown` could be an `any[]`, but that does not matter because `unknown` is only assignable to itself and `any`.  Also, note that you are using constant values for the left hand side of the conditional type clause.  If it was a generic that extended `unknown`, then you are correct, it may be `true` or `false`.  However, you passed in the `unknown` type so it must always be `false` unless explicitly casted into a compatible type.