# Why doesn't my TS Boolean override work for `any` or `unknown`?

Tags: typescript

I want `Boolean(truthy)` to yield a type of `true` instead of `Boolean`, and likewise for `falsy => false`

So I wrote this:

```
interface BooleanConstructor {
  <T extends false | 0 | '' | null | undefined>(value?: T): false;
  <T extends Record<any, any> | string | number | true>(value?: T): true;
  <T>(value?: T): boolean;
}
```

Works great, *except* for `any` and `unknown`.  Any ideas?

```
const A = Boolean(42 as any);     // false ??
const B = Boolean(42 as unknown); // boolean
const A2 = Boolean('');           // false
const B2 = Boolean(0);            // false
const C = Boolean(42);            // true
const D = Boolean('hello');       // true
const E = Boolean(true);          // true
const F = Boolean(false);         // false
const G = Boolean(null);          // false
const H = Boolean(undefined);     // false
const I = Boolean([]);            // true
const J = Boolean({});            // true
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwCMccIAeAFXhAA8MRVgBnJKCRhAH3gAZ4uByfn3ipkECMLShEWVCGAA+ABQA3VshAB+AFzxyASl2JW7ANwAoUJFgIU6bHkLEylGnQbMASuBwxgpKFQATwAaeECghWFGDBhZAHNhUQBbAhAYYViNZTUIDR09Q3gskAsraDgkNExcfCISChz1LV0DXXqIEECLczA8GPgAQXgAXicSJQAWACZw5gj9U3hl5YB6VZY2BE1NXv6MeAAhUfGIKdmoZjQAa1QcAHdURfh1067UPdQBwdmxjqVBM8VsCVq9jFtPgNDr9TkpuECQSCwSYQJCDgBhE7-GYIxGgjYlNHwAAiWOcAIAFiBxDh+Lj8cUYBoiQBRMkTEr0pEEpmovpfA4AMXZZ3B7C5DLFfP28AA4iKlKJxBLJSiiQAJBVSEAyOTAenIiH8gYASQVAG0ALoq4GvQnGg4AKQVAG8AL42hklIA) with a local function instead, but same same.

Comment: Hmm, this one is weird: `<T extends Record<any, any> | any | true>(value?: T): true;` this actually matches the `unknown`. If `| any` is removed then `B` is `boolean`. However, `A` picks whatever the first overload is and uses its return value. If you swap the first two, then `A` is inferred as `true`. https://tsplay.dev/m043Rm

Comment: whoops, the `| any` was me testing.  Removed and fixed the playground link.  I guess the only problem is `any` which resolves to `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Boolean(42 as any)` can match either overload (because `any` matches anything), so it will resolve whichever comes first. If you swap your overload order, you'll get `true` instead of `false` here.

For a hack that might work, see this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwCMccIAeAFXhAA8MRVgBneAb3gG0ADAAWDwwC0IAG4gYA5IxACMACyyMBABxg4lYjAE9OAXQBcrAL7xDAPgAUwqBGQgD5AJQGiJEFFQAoUJFgIU6bDxCYjJKGjoGZkRrKXgAH3gABnj4AHJUlNRkCAgUtFBELFQQYAsrGxAAfnsnJBiQAG4vcGg4JDRMXHwXUKpaeiZ4ACVwHBhgUndNABp4KdMUxgwYIoBzTOQAWwIxFOXbMutbavhHA33G5p82-06gnopDipOz4Nd3Jo8wPCX4AEF4ABeN4QcwAFgATHNmFMHA14AiEQB6JF1CCxSqVL4-DDwABCQJB4KhUGYaAA1qgcAB3VBw%20AokFuTzfVC-P5Q4E9czpemI-mIxnRdEgbFs3F4zlExJ8gUCoX1MW-ADChO5kNlcsFqIuStxABE1SEebIQDkcKlNdr4LrWb8AKJGkjmC5W%20U6mC2PXwABiTtBwqkbutgdFdtxAHF-eYsjlgyHFeH4AAJaP5ECFYrAK0KkXegCS0fYOnj-MZtpx8AAUtGWIZS9aLkA). Basically, you need a new overload where `T` looks for a type that won't match any of your other overloads to go first, something like:

```
interface BooleanContstructor {
  <T extends { [`@hopefully-this-long-string-will-never-be-used-as-a-property`]: {} }>(value: T): boolean
  // ...
```

Or, do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927523/disallow-call-with-any/49928360#49928360).

Comment: yeah, so... any ideas on how to fix it so that `any` resolves to `boolean`?  It doesn't seem possible to match the `any` type specifically

Comment: While I see the usefulness of what you are trying to accomplish, the way `any` works makes this impossible.

Comment: Not buying that, lol

Comment: Okay, after a bit of investigation, I acknowledge it is not impossible, but you might not like the solution: if you create a specific type (i.e. not `any` or `unknown`) that doesn't match any of your other cases, you can get this to work. I'll attach a playground to my answer.

Comment: @Voice see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927523/disallow-call-with-any/49928360#49928360

Comment: haha, that's genius, just match an impossible type.

Comment: FYI jcalz's linked answer to a similar scenario looks less gross.

Comment: yeah, neither actually quite works.  `Boolean(undefined)` catches for some reason??  Especially confusing since the `IfAny` type doesn't catch it if it's just the type, but it does in a function signature

Comment: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZgQQHYgDwBUA0UCa2ByAfFALxQAMUEAHsBEgCYDOUAFAIxQBkU6AlFAD8uKAC4o+ANxQAUDIYQAxgBsAhgCdocAK5JFwAJYB7JFABGRo8oxVa9ZrEQoM2YOu0RsSCADcI6wkJWH1VlD0FxfnEAckVVbQBzAAtgaPklNU0oHT1DE3NLa3RbOkYWOFCmaAAfCiha6Oj6qCRtZWVm3QU4A28GIJCwiAjePnEK5SrJdJUNLV19Y1MLKxsaUocAJSUjdQZUVRRsQ5BiWqY3XoTm1oBbM39mtw8B0PDIsahniGmFWaycot8isiq8hiMogUrBBDtMZIoTBcoAhSFDlKwACwAJigqhYJz40igxKgAHpSdlKtBBIJ4YjgFAAEKokGYnF4qC6ADWSCMAHckISyRSQTCkHSkEiABIswqsLoQHp9IUk4WUyYQGRAA)

Comment: FYI this is resolved by making the argument in the function signature that checks for any non-optional: `(value: T)` vs `(value?: T)`.  `undefined` seems to act as `any` inside of generics if it's optional, which definitely seems like a TS bug, and I reported it

Comment: Not a bug, because making a parameter optional with [`?` implicitly allows `undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters:~:text=the%20x%20parameter%20will%20actually%20have%20the%20type%20number%20%7C%20undefined).

Comment: Yes, `undefined`, not `any`.  The issue is that `<T extends 42>(arg?: T)` passes if you call `fn()`.  `undefined` does not extend `42`