# What is the best way to define Typescript type predicates that result in the most narrow types when used to filter arrays?

Tags: typescript, types, predicate

I thought I had found the best way to define predicates:

```
declare function isNumber<T>(x: T): x is Extract<T, number>;
declare function isFunction<T>(x: T): x is Extract<T, Function>;
... and so on
```

This approach results in nicely narrowed types when used to filter arrays, for example:

```
type Handler = () => void;

declare const a: (number|string)[];
declare const b: string[];
declare const c: (Handler|null)[];

const a1 = a.filter(isNumber);    // number[]  
const b1 = b.filter(isNumber);    // never[]   
const c1 = c.filter(isFunction);  // Handler[]
```

Unfortunately, `unknown` and `any` result in surprising behavior:

```
declare const d: any[];
declare const e: unknown[];

const d1 = d.filter(isNumber);  // any[]    want number[]
const e1 = e.filter(isNumber);  // never[]  want number[]
```

So it wasn't the best way after all! However, even the approach in the Typescript handbook for defining predicates behaves "weirdly" when used for filtering:

```
declare function isNumber2(x: any): x is number;
declare function isFunction2(x: any): x is Function;

const a2 = a.filter(isNumber2);    // number[]         
const b2 = b.filter(isNumber2);    // string[]          want never[]
const c2 = c.filter(isFunction2);  // (Handler|null)[]  want Handler[]
const d2 = d.filter(isNumber2);    // number[]         
const e2 = e.filter(isNumber2);    // number[]
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXywGcA5ZAWwCMQYAeAFQD4AKADwC546BKDlgw%20AFEWGGFEz0ANPFTkqMBgG4AUKEiwEKdNjz8AYmky5U9Zu0494fIkJFiJdaQe3Gly5RgCeABwQAJKFRgCGp4AF54Ji5whngANxwsYBVVcGg4eDA8Qgx4KA4mWUpqAB8cmCxUAHMuAG0AXRU1dIQs1Bz4Cg5yyqqGprSNTOzcsAKAoJCYEtkICDrG9zaOqABGcLyAOkQsCAxqJiJSYpguRXgLi4B6K5k5agaLwF4NwFkd5WXcinWIim3d-ZghxI91O50u8BuMhAcQe9Uur3eI0y30yfz2ByIziMeDOl0hE2CsPgCNS6gyH3gwA4gU8-VJLWG7VyIA4aAA1qgcAB3VB0xFMyko4BogFA47yXHgyE0x7gp6ASj34FzArkivIGvyOiAUSARRjgSdJXjbqhoUTnorlahVSCNfShlpsfgjiCAExMOJQCDIFl5VCeSye70IGxq6gDMmaQw6Z2ELEx91Bn3U-2Br0%20-jwePGFIUqCujZQPWAl0nV1GiEm21w8Fyt4UigFn7FsVuiuQnrVWW1i1KlVQmEwDUUsBN1E7dEluPR4zlsGQpgEqYzZBzBbEy39pewzW5YBj4UT0Wl%20RzqVVk7dnsIikgMe6o-68XUM-Gu6Xms94lvIA)

I've spent way too long trying various approaches, like overloads, generic param constraints, etc., to get this to work for all of the above cases, but getting nowhere. Is there a way to define predicates that nicely narrow arrays when filtered? (Sorry, I know "nicely" is subjective. Generally it would be the most narrow intended type.) Or do I just need to choose an approach that is tolerable? Also looking for guidance that I'm totally on the wrong path as I'm currently learning Typescript.

Comment: There's a *lot* going on here; you are trying to bend TS to your will instead of accepting what it does.  Type predicates tend to do some combination of union filtering and intersections, and `any` tends to be "infectious".  If you really want to try to force all those to work as you expect, you could try something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpzOMw) but I would think few people would want such monsters in their code base.   I can write this up as an answer if you want, but I'm not sure if it meets your needs or whatever the underlying use case is. Thoughts?

Comment: @jcalz This is excellent, thank you! Just the guidance I needed.

Just curious in what way this is asking too much from the type system. I want to learn how to think the Typescript way.

I've annotated your solution with my understanding [here](https://tsplay.dev/NrEP5w), including a simplification that I _think_ is equivalent. I want to be respectful of your time/effort, but an answer would be illuminating if you think my analysis is off track, otherwise happy to trudge through the corner cases on my own.

Comment: Wait, are you saying I should only write up an answer if your own version of my code is incorrect in some way?  If you could make it simple for me and give me a  or a  on writing an answer that doesn't involve another major round of code analysis that would be helpful.

Comment: I would love to hear an explanation of your answer as you originally wrote it. Thank you!

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance, it will be a number of hours because it is now past my bedtime.

Comment: No rush at all. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: TypeScript's [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) behavior is essentially a mixture of various heuristics that work over a wide range of real-world use cases; there will always be edge cases where you'd like it to act differently. Trying to preemptively account for all these edge cases in a one-size-fits-all [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) is going to involve a lot of fiddly type juggling, and result in an unintuitive and complicated call signature.  And there will still be edge cases, so at some point it's not worth the diminishing returns you get by accounting for them.  In what follows I will describe one possible approach which handles the cases from the example code in the question, but just because it's possible does not imply it's advisable. That depends on use cases, and is ultimately out of scope for the question as asked.

---

My goal is to produce a utility type `TypePred<T, U>` such that

```
declare function isNumber<T>(x: T): x is TypePred<T, number>;
declare function isFunction<T>(x: T): x is TypePred<T, Function>
```

behaves as you desire.  First, no matter what, TypeScript needs to see `TypePred<T, U>` as assignable to `T`, even for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `T`. The easiest way to do that is to use [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) on the result of our intended narrowing:

```
type TypePred<T, U> =
    Extract<⋯, T>;
```

This will have no ultimate effect as long as the `⋯` type is indeed assignable to `T` when you fill in some type argument for `T`, but it will prevent any compiler errors in the type predicate.

Now we'll take care of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  Just about any type manipulation involving `any` will evaluate to `any`; it's "infectious".  Both `any & X` and `any | X` evaluate to `any`. So it takes care not to have `TypePred<any, U>` evaluate to `any`.  There's a technique described in the answer to [Disallow call with any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49927523/2887218) for detecting `any`, which is essentially just witnessing the weird behavior and detecting a supposedly impossible situation of an intersection widening a type. If `T` is `any` then we just want to return `U`.  So now we have:

```
type TypePred<T, U> =
    Extract<0 extends (1 & T) ? ⋯, T>;
```

Now we can finally start dealing with more general cases.  The `Extract` utility type is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) that serves to filter [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). It looks like `T extends U ? T : never`.  The `? T` part of that is good.  Every union member of `T` that's a subtype of `U` can be returned as-is.  It's just that the `never` part ends up dropping things which have some *overlap* with `U`, like `unknown`. So now we have:

```
type TypePred<T, U> =
    Extract<0 extends (1 & T) ? U : T extends U ? T : ⋯, T>;
```

So, finally, we have to deal with `T` (or any union member of `T`) that is not already a subtype of `U`, but which might have some overlap with `U`, and produce a subtype of `T` *and* `U` from it.  The only facility TS has for this in general is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `T & U`.

Which gives us

```
type TypePred<T, U> =
    Extract<0 extends (1 & T) ? U : T extends U ? T : (T & U), T>;
```

---

Let's test it out on your examples:

```
declare const a: (number | string)[];
const a1 = a.filter(isNumber); // number[]  

declare const b: string[];
const b1 = b.filter(isNumber); // never[]   

type Handler = () => void;
declare const c: (Handler | null)[];
const c1 = c.filter(isFunction);// Handler[] 

declare const d: any[];
const d1 = d.filter(isNumber); // number[]

declare const e: unknown[];
const e1 = e.filter(isNumber); // number[]
```

Looks good, that's the behavior you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEAUBOEAmAeGAaKBVAfFALwBQU5UAogB7BICGAxsOgAxQS0QB2qAzlAAUARigAyWAEooAfjxQAXLA5deA3LOVLBMcXkk4Y+ANwkSqCIwA29FFABmAV27MAlgHtuUV3wByjgFsAIwgkTHxBaiUYSSVqbwE4SGQ0TBxuQJCkE3NLGzsnF2APLx8AMWc3T3DI6NioeJ9YeBSMbCgKopL8MwtrW2hGTz5gKHptDODQqAAfKBGkV24Ac0kAbQBdUyHuEbHRIjGAOntXK2BQwR9-KaRJYygAekeoSazN8l68gagdvaClAslstNtthqMggcoEETmcLkgrn5MqF7k8XtwIAA3UIfT4kUCQKAACXovCs00OgmkREImPcrlQpj6+UG4N+2hJZOmcwyVis6y2JD+o0YUMYsPOl3KlWKnnuz2JpNQ5KQHy+-TswqgqCUpJAoKFbNQUNQEvhiJuWVRCreOI26pZvzZECUzgA1tx3AB3bgGrUQKEQM1SpG3a3o5Gq+1mIA)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use generics and a conditional type assertion to achieve what you want.

```
declare function isNumber<T>(value: T): value is T extends number ? T : never;
declare function isFunction<T>(value: T): value is T extends Function ? T : never;
```

The above gave me the output I would expect for each of your examples.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I think I tried something similar. Unfortunately, this approach also struggles with `any[]` and `unknown[]`, resulting in `any[]` and `never[]` respectively when filtered, rather than `number[]`. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZBPam)